# How to get an enum value from a string value in Java

Tags: java, enums

Say I have an enum which is just

```
public enum Blah {
    A, B, C, D
}
```

and I would like to find the enum value of a string, for example `"A"` which would be `Blah.A`. How would it be possible to do this?

Is the [`Enum.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)) the method I need? If so, how would I use this?

Comment: Here is a solution which not only does this, but covers doing so ignoring case sensitivity, and moves the solution from O(N) to O(1): https://stackoverflow.com/a/74408971/501113

Answer (score 2622, accepted):

Yes, `Blah.valueOf("A")` will give you `Blah.A`.

Note that the name must be an *exact* match, including case: `Blah.valueOf("a")` and `Blah.valueOf("A ")` both throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

The static methods `valueOf()` and `values()` are created at compile time and do not appear in source code. They do appear in Javadoc, though; for example, [`Dialog.ModalityType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html) shows both methods.

Comment: For reference, the `Blah.valueOf("A")` method is ***case sensitive*** and doesn't tolerate extraneous whitespace, thus the alternate solution proposed below by @JoséMi.

Comment: @Michael Myers, Since this answer is the most voted up by far, should I understand that it's good practice to define an enum and its String value to be exactly the same?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: If you mean the `toString()` value, no, I wouldn't say that. `name()` will get you the actual defined name of the enum constant unless you override it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "are created at compile time and do not appear in source code." ?

Comment: @treesAreEverywhere More specifically, those methods are _generated_ (or _synthesized_) by the compiler.  The actual `enum Blah {...}` definition shouldn't try to declare its own `values` nor `valuesOf`.  It's like how you can write "AnyTypeName.class" even though you never actually declared a "class" member variable; the compiler makes it all Just Work.  (This answer may no longer be useful to you 3 months later, but just in case.)

Comment: Great answer--in addition I've found adding a few little helper methods to enums helps a lot... For instance, if you create a static map of lower-case entries in the constructor then you can add a method that looks the enum up in a case-insensitive way, or converts underbars to spaces so user input like "Second Entry" could map to an enum SECOND_ENTRY.

Comment: Upvote, but this post would be even better with a mention of Enum::name

Comment: This doesn't work on my case, I am still getting IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul: Sounds like it's not an exact case-correct match then.

Comment: "Blah.valueOf("A") method is case sensitive" of course it is, upper-casing enum constants is only a convention - Java allows to have constants that only differ in character case.

Comment: Here is a solution covering ignoring case sensitivity, and moves the solution from O(N) to O(1): stackoverflow.com/a/74408971/501113

Answer (score 1055):

Another solution if the text is not the same as the enumeration value:

```
public enum Blah {
    A("text1"),
    B("text2"),
    C("text3"),
    D("text4");

    private String text;

    Blah(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public static Blah fromString(String text) {
        for (Blah b : Blah.values()) {
            if (b.text.equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `throw new IllegalArgumentException("No constant with text " + text + " found")` would be better than `return null`.

Comment: @Sangdol usually it's a good thing to check what SUN - oops - Oracle is doing in the same situation. And as [Enum.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf) is showing it **IS** best practice to throw a Exception in this case. *Because* it is an exceptional situation. "Performance optimization" is a bad excuse to write unreadable code ;-)

Comment: Here is a solution covering ignoring case sensitivity, and moves the solution from O(N) to O(1): stackoverflow.com/a/74408971/501113

Answer (score 165):

Use the pattern from [Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch), *Effective Java*:

(simplified for brevity)

```
enum MyEnum {
    ENUM_1("A"),
    ENUM_2("B");

    private String name;

    private static final Map<String,MyEnum> ENUM_MAP;

    MyEnum (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // Build an immutable map of String name to enum pairs.
    // Any Map impl can be used.

    static {
        Map<String,MyEnum> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyEnum>();
        for (MyEnum instance : MyEnum.values()) {
            map.put(instance.getName().toLowerCase(),instance);
        }
        ENUM_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    public static MyEnum get (String name) {
        return ENUM_MAP.get(name.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Also see:

[Oracle Java Example using Enum and Map of instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e12267)

[Execution order of of static blocks in an Enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776698/execution-order-of-of-static-blocks-in-an-enum-type-w-r-t-to-constructor)

[How can I lookup a Java enum from its String value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080904/how-can-i-lookup-a-java-enum-from-its-string-value)

Comment: This is even simpler in Java 8 as you can do :`Stream.of(MyEnum.values()).collect(toMap(Enum::name, identity()))`
I also recommend overriding toString() (passed in through constructor) and using that instead of name, especially if the Enum is associated with serializable data as this lets you control the casing without giving Sonar a fit.

Comment: [Static initialization is inherently synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2), so there's absolutely no reason to use `ConcurrentHashMap` here, where the map is never modified after initialization. Hence why even e.g. the example in the JLS itself uses a regular `HashMap`.

Comment: In Kotlin this sort of looks like (without lowercase):
`
        private val mapStringToEnum by lazy { values().associateBy { it.name } }

        fun get(name: String): MyEnum? {
            return mapStringToEnum[name]
        }
`

Answer (score 135):

Here's a nifty utility I use:

```
/**
 * A common method for all enums since they can't have another base class
 * @param <T> Enum type
 * @param c enum type. All enums must be all caps.
 * @param string case insensitive
 * @return corresponding enum, or null
 */
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T getEnumFromString(Class<T> c, String string) {
    if( c != null && string != null ) {
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(c, string.trim().toUpperCase());
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then in my enum class I usually have this to save some typing:

```
public static MyEnum fromString(String name) {
    return getEnumFromString(MyEnum.class, name);
}
```

If your enums are not all caps, just change the `Enum.valueOf` line.

It is too bad I can't use `T.class` for `Enum.valueOf` as `T` is erased.

Comment: That empty catch block really drives me nuts, sorry.

Comment: @LazloBonin: Exceptions are for exceptional conditions, not for control flow. Get yourself a copy of [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/).

Comment: Horrible! Always, **always** catch exceptions where you can handle them. The example above is a perfect example **how to NOT do it**. Why? So it returns NULL, and the caller then has to check against NULL or throw a NPE. If the caller knows how to handle the situation then doing an if vs. try-catch may look a bit more elegant, **BUT** if he can't handle he has to pass null again and the caller of the caller **again** has to check against NULL, etc. etc.

Comment: @whiskeysierra I understand being passionate about Java or software development is one thing but you gotta chill man. No benefit in geeking out/being extra like this.

Comment: What about returning Optional instead of nullable ?

Answer (score 81):

You should also be careful with your case. Let me explain: doing `Blah.valueOf("A")` works, but `Blah.valueOf("a")` will not work. Then again `Blah.valueOf("a".toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH))` would work.

On Android you should use [`Locale.US`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#default_locale), as [sulai points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-convert-string-to-enum/843600#comment27337289_843600).

Comment: Be wary of the default locale!

Answer (score 56):

In Java 8 or later, using [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/):

```
public enum Blah
{
    A("text1"),
    B("text2"),
    C("text3"),
    D("text4");

    private String text;

    Blah(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public static Optional<Blah> fromText(String text) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
          .filter(bl -> bl.text.equalsIgnoreCase(text))
          .findFirst();
    }
}
```

Comment: Java 8 did some good things and while I like Streams (for concurrency mostly)... this is actually NOT a reason to use them. It buys the OP nothing and performs more poorly ... simply substituting a for/next loop through all items for a Stream version of the same (and not even in parallel). For a few entries.... who cares but to be clear, this is not some "it is way better because of Java 8" example. It's just a fluent-style green vs blue 'different' implementation of the same returning an Optional vs null (and fluent-style requires a non-null return for all joined methods).

Answer (score 41):

Here's a method that can do it for any Enum, and is case insensitive.

```
/** 
 * Finds the value of the given enumeration by name, case-insensitive. 
 * Throws an IllegalArgumentException if no match is found.  
 **/
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOfIgnoreCase(
        Class<T> enumeration, String name) {

    for (T enumValue : enumeration.getEnumConstants()) {
        if (enumValue.name().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            return enumValue;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
        "There is no value with name '%s' in Enum %s",
        name, enumeration.getName()
    ));
}
```

Comment: Good use of Generics but not sure IllegalArgumentException is really the right contract here. First, it is entirely possible (and expected?) that a lookup will fail... it is isn't in the collection (enum really) per se. Throwing a RuntimeException "propagate[s] outside the method". Since that is not in the method signature - a caller would not expect it. Better to use Map construct (return null on not found) or perhaps even better... Optional.empty().

Answer (score 40):

Using `Blah.valueOf(string)` is best, but you can use `Enum.valueOf(Blah.class, string)` as well.

Answer (score 40):

My two cents here: using Java 8 Streams and checking an exact string:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE_1("Super"),
    VALUE_2("Rainbow"),
    VALUE_3("Dash"),
    VALUE_3("Rocks");

    private final String value;

    MyEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * @return the Enum representation for the given string.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if unknown string.
     */
    public static MyEnum fromString(String s) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values())
                .filter(v -> v.value.equals(s))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("unknown value: " + s));
    }
}
```

I renamed the function to `fromString()` since naming it using that convention, you'll obtain some benefits from Java language itself; for example:

1. [Direct conversion of types at HeaderParam annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/HeaderParam.html)

Comment: As on other answers already commented, what is the benefit or drawback of using streams for the conversion. This is the way I'd do it too, but I'm just curious why this approach is better than simple loops of calling of Enum.valueOf(class, value)

Answer (score 34):

If you don't want to write your own utility, use Google's [guava](/questions/tagged/guava) library:

```
Enums.getIfPresent(Blah.class, "A")
```

Unlike the built-in Java function, it let's you check if A is present in Blah and doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 17):

You may need to this:

```
public enum ObjectType {
    PERSON("Person");

    public String parameterName;

    ObjectType(String parameterName) {
        this.parameterName = parameterName;
    }

    public String getParameterName() {
        return this.parameterName;
    }

    // From the String method, it will return you the Enum for the provided input string
    public static ObjectType fromString(String parameterName) {
        if (parameterName != null) {
            for (ObjectType objType : ObjectType.values()) {
                if (parameterName.equalsIgnoreCase(objType.parameterName)) {
                    return objType;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### One more addition

```
   public static String fromEnumName(String parameterName) {
        if (parameterName != null) {
            for (DQJ objType : DQJ.values()) {
                if (parameterName.equalsIgnoreCase(objType.name())) {
                    return objType.parameterName;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This will return you the Value by a Stringified Enum Name. For example, if you provide "PERSON" in the fromEnumName it'll return you the Value of Enum, i.e., "Person".

Answer (score 15):

Another way of doing this is by using the implicit static method `name()` of Enum. *name* will return the exact string used to create that enum which can be used to check against the provided string:

```
public enum Blah {

    A, B, C, D;

    public static Blah getEnum(String s){
        if(A.name().equals(s)){
            return A;
        }else if(B.name().equals(s)){
            return B;
        }else if(C.name().equals(s)){
            return C;
        }else if (D.name().equals(s)){
            return D;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Enum specified for this string");
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
System.out.println(Blah.getEnum("B").name());


// It will print B  B
```

Inspiration: *[10 Examples of Enum in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html)*

Answer (score 14):

In Java 8 the static Map pattern is even easier and is my preferred method. If you want to use the Enum with Jackson you can override toString and use that instead of name, then annotate with `@JsonValue`

```
public enum MyEnum {
    BAR,
    BAZ;
    private static final Map<String, MyEnum> MAP = Stream.of(MyEnum.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Enum::name, Function.identity()));
    public static MyEnum fromName(String name){
        return MAP.get(name);
    }
}

public enum MyEnumForJson {
    BAR("bar"),
    BAZ("baz");
    private static final Map<String, MyEnumForJson> MAP = Stream.of(MyEnumForJson.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::toString, Function.identity()));
    private final String value;

    MyEnumForJson(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

    public static MyEnumForJson fromValue(String value){
        return MAP.get(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obfuscated code contest runner up? I mean this is technically correct. :-) ... but it is unessarily obtuse for a simple for/next loop over a Map - which arguably is no better an impl than earlier versions of Java could provide. private static final Map<String, MyEnumForJson> MAP = Stream.of(MyEnumForJson.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::toString, Function.identity()));

Comment: I think streams just look obtuse when you're used to for loops, but to each their own

Answer (score 13):

Enum is very useful. I have been using `Enum` a lot to add a description for some fields in different languages, as the following example:

```
public enum Status {

    ACT(new String[] { "Accepted", "مقبول" }),
    REJ(new String[] { "Rejected", "مرفوض" }),
    PND(new String[] { "Pending", "في الانتظار" }),
    ERR(new String[] { "Error", "خطأ" }),
    SNT(new String[] { "Sent", "أرسلت" });

    private String[] status;

    public String getDescription(String lang) {
        return lang.equals("en") ? status[0] : status[1];
    }

    Status(String[] status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

And then you can retrieve the description dynamically based in the language code passed to the `getDescription(String lang)` method, for example:

```
String statusDescription = Status.valueOf("ACT").getDescription("en");
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution using [Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) libraries. Method getPlanet() is case insensitive, so getPlanet ("MerCUrY") will return Planet.MERCURY.

```
package com.universe.solarsystem.planets;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import com.google.common.base.Enums;
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

//Pluto and Eris are dwarf planets, who cares!
public enum Planet {
   MERCURY,
   VENUS,
   EARTH,
   MARS,
   JUPITER,
   SATURN,
   URANUS,
   NEPTUNE;

   public static Planet getPlanet(String name) {
      String val = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(name).toUpperCase();
      Optional <Planet> possible = Enums.getIfPresent(Planet.class, val);
      if (!possible.isPresent()) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(val + "? There is no such planet!");
      }
      return possible.get();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

To add to the previous answers, and address some of the discussions around nulls and [NPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#Dereferencing) I'm using [Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) *Optionals* to handle absent/invalid cases.  This works great for URI and parameter parsing.

```
public enum E {
    A,B,C;
    public static Optional<E> fromString(String s) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(E.valueOf(s.toUpperCase()));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException|NullPointerException e) {
            return Optional.absent();
        }
    }
}
```

For those not aware, here's some more information on avoiding null with *[Optional](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained#Optional)*.

Answer (score 9):

Apache's [Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library has static function [org.apache.commons.lang3.EnumUtils.getEnum](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release//org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html#getEnum(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) which will map a String to your `Enum` type. Same answer essentially as [Geoffrey Zheng's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/how-to-get-an-enum-value-from-a-string-value-in-java/1723239#1723239), but there isn't any need to roll your own when it's out there in the wild already.

Comment: It would be good to add an usage example, as EnumUtils is not as convenient as one may hope (it requires the class as argument).

Answer (score 8):

An O(1) method inspired from [Thrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Thrift)-generated code which uses a hashmap.

```
public enum USER {
        STUDENT("jon",0),TEACHER("tom",1);

        private static final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        static {
                for (USER user : EnumSet.allOf(USER.class)) {
                        map.put(user.getTypeName(), user.getIndex());
                }
        }

        public static int findIndexByTypeName(String typeName) {
                return map.get(typeName);
        }

        private USER(String typeName,int index){
                this.typeName = typeName;
                this.index = index;
        }
        private String typeName;
        private int index;
        public String getTypeName() {
                return typeName;
        }
        public void setTypeName(String typeName) {
                this.typeName = typeName;
        }
        public int getIndex() {
                return index;
        }
        public void setIndex(int index) {
                this.index = index;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public static MyEnum getFromValue(String value) {
    MyEnum resp = null;
    MyEnum nodes[] = values();
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if(nodes[i].value.equals(value)) {
            resp = nodes[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`java.lang.Enum` defines several useful methods, which is available to all enumeration types in Java:

- You can use the `name()` method to get the name of any Enum constants. The string literal used to write enum constants is their name.
- Similarly, the `values()` method can be used to get an array of all Enum constants from an Enum type.
- And for the asked question, you can use the `valueOf()` method to convert any String to an Enum constant in Java, as shown below.

```
public class EnumDemo06 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Gender fromString = Gender.valueOf("MALE");
        System.out.println("Gender.MALE.name() : " + fromString.name());
    }

    private enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE;
    }
}

Output:
Gender.MALE.name() : MALE
```

In this code snippet, the `valueOf()` method returns an Enum constant, *Gender.MALE*, and calling name on that returns `"MALE"`.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD;

    public static Optional<MyEnum> fromString(String value) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(MyEnum.valueOf(value));
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Enum valueOf()

An enum class automatically gets a static valueOf() method in the class when compiled. The valueOf() method can be used to obtain an instance of the enum class for a given String value.

For example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Strings.TWO.name());
    }
    enum Strings {
        ONE, TWO, THREE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding on to [Michael Myers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/how-to-get-an-enum-value-from-a-string-value-in-java/604426#604426), with a helpful utility...

`valueOf()` throws two different Exceptions in cases where it doesn't like its input.

- `IllegalArgumentException`
- `NullPointerExeption`

If your requirements are such that you don't have any guarantee that your String will definitely match an enum value, for example if the String data comes from a database and could contain old version of the enum, then you'll need to handle these often...

So here's a reusable method I wrote which allows us to define a default Enum to be returned if the String we pass doesn't match.

```
private static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf( String name , T defaultVal) {
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(defaultVal.getDeclaringClass() , name);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e) {
            return defaultVal;
        }
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
public enum MYTHINGS {
    THINGONE,
    THINGTWO
}

public static void main(String [] asd) {
  valueOf("THINGTWO" , MYTHINGS.THINGONE);//returns MYTHINGS.THINGTWO
  valueOf("THINGZERO" , MYTHINGS.THINGONE);//returns MYTHINGS.THINGONE
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As a `switch`-version has not been mentioned yet I introduce it (reusing OP's enum):

```
  private enum Blah {
    A, B, C, D;

    public static Blah byName(String name) {
      switch (name) {
        case "A":
          return A;
        case "B":
          return B;
        case "C":
          return C;
        case "D":
          return D;
        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "No enum constant " + Blah.class.getCanonicalName() + "." + name);
      }
    }
  }
```

Since this don't give any additional value to the `valueOf(String name)` method, it only makes sense to define an additional method if we want have a different behavior. If we don't want to raise an `IllegalArgumentException` we can change the implementation to:

```
  private enum Blah {
    A, B, C, D;

    public static Blah valueOfOrDefault(String name, Blah defaultValue) {
      switch (name) {
        case "A":
          return A;
        case "B":
          return B;
        case "C":
          return C;
        case "D":
          return D;
        default:
          if (defaultValue == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
          }
          return defaultValue;
      }
    }
  }
```

By providing a default value we keep the [contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)) of `Enum.valueOf(String name)` without throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`  in that manner that in no case `null` is returned. Therefore we throw a `NullPointerException` if the name is `null` and in case of `default` if `defaultValue` is `null`. That's how `valueOfOrDefault` works.

This approach adopts the design of the `Map`-Interface which provides a method `Map.getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)` as of Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for an answer to find the "blah" name and not its value (not the text). Based on [Manu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/how-to-get-an-enum-value-from-a-string-value-in-java/45082346#45082346), I find this code useful:

```
public enum Blah {
    A("text1"),
    B("text2"),
    C("text3"),
    D("text4");

private String text;

Blah(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getText() {
    return this.text;
}

public static Blah valueOfCode(String blahCode) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Blah blah = Arrays.stream(Blah.values())
            .filter(val -> val.name().equals(blahCode))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to resolve blah: " + blahCode));

    return blah;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum ToggleStatusUpdate {
    OFF("off", 1),
    ON("on", 2);
    
    private final String name;
    private final int position;
    
    private ToggleStatusUpdate(String name, int position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    
    public static int getPositionForName(String name) {
        for(ToggleStatusUpdate toggleStatusUpdate : ToggleStatusUpdate.values()) {
            if (toggleStatusUpdate.getName().equals(name)) {
                return toggleStatusUpdate.getPosition();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ToggleStatusUpdate.getPositionForName("off"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of iterating every time when the `getPositionForName()` method is called we can create static Map holding name to Enum mapping. It will precompute the mapping and every method call will not iterate the enum values. As we are fetching it from map it is O(1) operation.

Answer (score 1):

Another utility capturing in reverse way. Using a value which identify that Enum, not from its name.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class EnumUtil {

    /**
     * Returns the <code>Enum</code> of type <code>enumType</code> whose a 
     * public method return value of this Enum is 
     * equal to <code>valor</code>.<br/>
     * Such method should be unique public, not final and static method 
     * declared in Enum.
     * In case of more than one method in match those conditions
     * its first one will be chosen.
     * 
     * @param enumType
     * @param value
     * @return 
     */
    public static <E extends Enum<E>> E from(Class<E> enumType, Object value) {
        String methodName = getMethodIdentifier(enumType);
        return from(enumType, value, methodName);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the <code>Enum</code> of type <code>enumType</code> whose  
     * public method <code>methodName</code> return is 
     * equal to <code>value</code>.<br/>
     *
     * @param enumType
     * @param value
     * @param methodName
     * @return
     */
    public static <E extends Enum<E>> E from(Class<E> enumType, Object value, String methodName) {
        EnumSet<E> enumSet = EnumSet.allOf(enumType);
        for (E en : enumSet) {
            try {
                String invoke = enumType.getMethod(methodName).invoke(en).toString();
                if (invoke.equals(value.toString())) {
                    return en;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String getMethodIdentifier(Class<?> enumType) {
        Method[] methods = enumType.getDeclaredMethods();
        String name = null;
        for (Method method : methods) {
            int mod = method.getModifiers();
            if (Modifier.isPublic(mod) && !Modifier.isStatic(mod) && !Modifier.isFinal(mod)) {
                name = method.getName();
                break;
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public enum Foo {
    ONE("eins"), TWO("zwei"), THREE("drei");

    private String value;

    private Foo(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

`EnumUtil.from(Foo.class, "drei")` returns `Foo.THREE`, because it will use `getValue` to match "drei", which is unique public, not final and not static method in Foo.
In case Foo has more than on public, not final and not static method, for example, `getTranslate` which returns "drei", the other method can be used: `EnumUtil.from(Foo.class, "drei", "getTranslate")`.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of answers and comments for Java 8 using Streams.
It creates a static Map for lookup with the opportunity of a default value, to prevent null checks.

```
public enum Blah {
    A, B, C, D, INVALID

    private static final Map<String, Blah> ENUM_MAP = Stream.of(Blah.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Enum::name, Function.identity()));

    public static Blah of(final String name) {
        return ENUM_MAP.getOrDefault(name, INVALID);
    }
}

// e.g.
Blah.of("A");
A

Blah.of("X")
INVALID
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this sort of process to parse commands as strings into enumerations.  I normally have one of the enumerations as "unknown" so it helps to have that returned when the others are not found (even on a case insensitive basis) rather than null (that meaning there is no value).  Hence I use this approach.

```
static <E extends Enum<E>> Enum getEnumValue(String what, Class<E> enumClass) {
    Enum<E> unknown=null;
    for (Enum<E> enumVal: enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {  
        if (what.compareToIgnoreCase(enumVal.name()) == 0) {
            return enumVal;
        }
        if (enumVal.name().compareToIgnoreCase("unknown") == 0) {
            unknown=enumVal;
        }
    }  
    return unknown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get the name of enum is to create a map of enum text and values when the application start, and to get the name call the function Blah.getEnumName():

```
public enum Blah {
    A("text1"),
    B("text2"),
    C("text3"),
    D("text4");

    private String text;
    private HashMap<String, String> map;
    Blah(String text) {
    this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
      return this.text;
    }

    static{
      createMapOfTextAndName();
    }

    public static void createMapOfTextAndName() {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Blah b : Blah.values()) {
             map.put(b.getText(),b.name());
        }
    }
    public static String getEnumName(String text) {
        return map.get(text.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin Solution

Create an extension and then call `valueOf<MyEnum>("value")`. If the type is invalid, you'll get null and have to handle it

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> valueOf(type: String): T? {
    return try {
        java.lang.Enum.valueOf(T::class.java, type)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set a default value, calling `valueOf<MyEnum>("value", MyEnum.FALLBACK)`, and avoiding a null response. You can extend your specific enum to have the default be automatic

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> valueOf(type: String, default: T): T {
    return try {
        java.lang.Enum.valueOf(T::class.java, type)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        default
    }
}
```

Or if you want both, make the second:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> valueOf(type: String, default: T): T = valueOf<T>(type) ?: default
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum DivisionType {
DEFAULT(0){
    @Override
    public void sort(List<SigInUserDto> SigInUserDtos) {
        SigInUserDtos.sort(new SigInUserCoinsQueueComparator());
    }
},
ASSIGNPOINTS(1) {
    @Override
    public void sort(List<SigInUserDto> SigInUserDtos) {
        SigInUserDtos.sort(new SigInUserPointsComparator());
    }
},
ASSIGNEVENORDER(2) {
    @Override
    public void sort(List<SigInUserDto> SigInUserDtos) {
        SigInUserDtos.sort(new SigInUserOrderCountComparator());
    }
};

public final Integer label;

DivisionType(Integer label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public static DivisionType getTypeById(Integer id) {
    for (DivisionType value : DivisionType.values()) {
        if (value.label == id) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return DEFAULT;
}

public abstract void sort(List<SigInUserDto> SigInUserDtos);
}
```

Using enum:
DivisionType.getTypeById(object.getBalancingTypesId().intValue()).sort(sigInUserDtoList);

Here, sort() function is implemented(over-loaded) under each enum match.
So, based on object "object.getBalancingTypesId().intValue()" match value, particular enum match is invoked and sorted.