# If you have a String and the enum doesn't have a getSomething(String str) method, how do you look up the enum value?

Tags: java, enums

I need to set an enum value like so:

```
this.myEnum = ThirdPartyEnum.ABC;
```

But the value I have available to me is not in Enum form.

It's just a raw string:

```
"ABC"
```

The `ThirdPartyEnum` does not have a `ThirdPartyEnum.lookupEnumForString()`.

How do I translate the String

```
"ABC"
```

to:

```
ThirdPartyEnum.ABC
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How can I lookup a Java enum from its string value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1080904/851811)

Comment: Yes it id dup...I mean what are the chances this has not been asked before a few times

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
ThirdPartyEnum.valueOf("ABC");
```

Just to add, and relating to the `lookupEnumForString()` method you mentioned, if you wanted to search an enumerated value by one of its attributes, you could use `values()`. Note that `values()` is public, and you could also use it in case of a third party enum over which you don't have control.

```
public enum MyEnum {

    VAL1("1"), VAL2("2");

    String attr;
    private MyEnum(String attr){
        this.attr = attr;
    }
    public String getAttr() { return attr; }

    public static MyEnum getByAttr(String searchAttr) {
        for(MyEnum t : values()){
            if(searchAttr.equals(t.getAttr())){
                return t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Enum.valueOf()

[Enum.valueOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29)

Or

```
ThirdPartyEnum.valueOf("ABC");
```

**valueOf** is a default method that is defined for all Java Enum classes.

If you are into functional programming, Guava provides a method for creating a Function to get the valueOf.

[Enums.valueOfFunction](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Enums.html#valueOfFunction%28java.lang.Class%29)