# Reverse lookup for Java Enums with more than one value per key/constant?

Tags: java, enums, lookup, reverse-lookup

With an enum like this one where each key has several values

```
ABBR1("long text 1", "another description 1", "yet another one 1"), 
ABBR2("long text 2", "another description 2", "yet another one 2"), 
//and so on...
```

how can I reverse lookup an abbreviation (constant) by calling a method like `getAbbreviation(descriptionText)`?

I'm basically looking for an implementation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15402573/2018047), I think, but with the difference that each ENUM key (constant) has several values coming with it, and I want it to work with `getAbbreviation("long text 1")` as well as with `getAbbreviation("yet another one 2")`...

Is there an easy way to loop over each ENUM's (i.e. `ABBRn`'s) value fields, to populate a giant map, or is there maybe even a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relies on the fact that the enum member constructors are run before the static initializer. The initializer then caches the members and their long forms.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum Abbreviation {
    ABBR1("long text 1", "another description 1", "yet another one 1"), 
    ABBR2("long text 2", "another description 2", "yet another one 2"); 

    private static final Map<String, Abbreviation> ABBREVIATIONS = new HashMap<>();

    private String[] longForms;
    private Abbreviation(String... longForms) {
        this.longForms = longForms;
    }

    public String toString () {
        return Arrays.toString(longForms);
    }

    static {
        for(Abbreviation abbr : values()) {
            for(String longForm : abbr.longForms) {
                ABBREVIATIONS.put(longForm, abbr);
            }

        }
    }

    public static Abbreviation of(String longForm) {
        Abbreviation abbreviation = ABBREVIATIONS.get(longForm);
        if(abbreviation == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException(longForm + " cannot be abbreviated");
        return abbreviation;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Abbreviation a =  Abbreviation.of("yet another one 2");
        System.out.println(a == Abbreviation.ABBR2); //true
    }
}
```

Comment: What would I have to change if I needed a reference for each of the argument's constructors, e.g. `private Abbreviation(String longText, String desc1, String desc2) { this.longText = longText; //etc`? I'm guessing `for(String longForm : abbr.longForms)` won't work for that?

Comment: I thought each abbreviation could have a variadic number of long forms. Since you have a fixed number of arguments, you'll need to construct an array with all 3 arguments for each enum member. `private Abbreviation(String longText, String desc1, String desc2) { this.longForms = new String[] {longText, desc1, desc2}; }`

Comment: So, there is no built-in way to loop over an (i.e. one single) ENUM **constant**'s values?

Answer (score 2):

Each enum has a method values() so You can do  like that:

```
for(YourEnum type : values()){
        if(/*is Equal to Your descriptionText*/){
             return type;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such BailiffPaymentStatus:"+dbRepresentation);
```

Comment: Do you know what Java class that `values()` method is defined? Is it the one in `java.lang Enum`? If so, that class must describe an ENUM constant and its values - which would raise the question where enum "classes" are defined...?

Comment: Yes it is defined in Enum class itself. If You would decompile Your enum, You would notice that is is more-or-less a quite simple class
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/enum/enum-converted-to-class/

Comment: @Christian There is no `values()` method in [`java.lang.Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), it's  a synthetic method of the actual enum type.

Comment: @kapep: I assume the type itself is implemented in Java? If so, is there a way to look at the source code? Just being curious...

Comment: @Christian It's compiler generated, so I don't think you can find a real source file. The java specification should contain some information about it though, and you can look at the code using `javap` - or just look at the code in the link maslan posted, it's a quite simple method that just returns an array of enum constants.

Comment: @Christian the real real source file does not exist, but by decompiling it, You can see the logic behind it, it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution from: c.P.u1 is on the right track.  However there is a more direct way to populate the HashMap as you go using the solution from this question.

- [How to facilitate Netbeans Designer to load JPanel-s that use an enum reverse-lookup using hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103797/108350)

  ```
      private static final Map<String, Abbreviation> abbreviationMap;

      private Abbreviation(String... longForms) {
          this.longForms = longForms;   //  optional
          mapAbbreviations( this, longForms )
      }

      private static void mapAbbreviations( final Status state, String... longForms ){
          if( null ==  abbreviationMap  ){
              abbreviationMap  = new HashMap( 20 );
          }
          for( String abbrev : longForms ){
              abbreviationMap.put( abbrev,  state );
          }
      }
  ```

Also, you don't really need the private `longForms` string array for the toString() function, since all the values are saved with the Map anyway.