# Get enum constant using its value

Tags: java, enums, kotlin

Im trying to get enum using its value but it throws an error saying `No enum constant`. The eg code is in Kotlin but it is same in Java Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*

enum class TaskAction constructor(val value: String) {
    ARCHIVE("Archive"), UN_FLAG("Un flag"), FLAG("Flag"), REDO("Redo"),
    READY("Ready"), EDIT("Edit"), DND("dnd"), DELETE("Delete"),
    IN_PROGRESS("In progress"), DONE("Done");
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    showSomeThing(TaskAction.UN_FLAG.value)
}

fun showSomeThing(enum: String) {
    println(TaskAction.valueOf(enum))
}
```

Log:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum
>   constant TaskAction.Un flag

Comment: "The eg code is in Kotlin but it is same in Java" - *what* is the same in Java? Given how many more people write Java than Kotlin, I'd strongly encourage you to write a Java question rather than a Kotlin one...

Comment: Maybe leave out `constructor`. Check this for comparison: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1080914/2392960

Comment: For tasks like this one — where you want to look up your enums by some attribute rather than their declared names — there are two standard solutions: (1) provide an automatic translation from value to name (like uppercase and replace space with underscore) (2) use a static `Map`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `valueOf` method takes a string that should correspond the *name* of the enum constant. However, you extract the value of the enum and try to map that back to a constant. This does not work unless the value is equal to the name of the constant.

So your problem is that `TaskAction.UN_FLAG.value` returns `"Un flag"`. Then you call `TaskAction.valueOf("Un flag")`, which cannot find any enum constant with the string you provided (because the name of the enum constant is `UN_FLAG`).

So basically: `"Un flag" != "UN_FLAG"`

Edit:

To fix the issue, I would create a function that finds the correct enum based on the value. I would place the function within the companion object of `TaskAction`. Like this:

```
companion object {
  fun from(s: String): TaskAction? = values().find { it.value == s }
}
```

Comment: Thank @marstran I know `"Un flag" != "UN_FLAG"`. I'm seeking for solution not explanation.

Comment: @SaiKiran See edit.

Answer (score 6):

I changed my enum class to something like below, I added a static Map. Because there is no way it maps the value and name by itself. I thought this may help some.

```
    enum class TaskAction constructor(val value: String) {
    ARCHIVE("Archive"), UN_FLAG("Un flag"), FLAG("Flag"), REDO("Redo"),
    READY("Ready"), EDIT("Edit"), DND("dnd"), DELETE("Delete"),
    IN_PROGRESS("In progress"), DONE("Done");

    companion object {
        private val lookup = HashMap<String, TaskAction>()

        init {
            TaskAction.values().map { lookup.put(it.value, it) }
        }

        fun getFromValue(value: String):TaskAction {
            return lookup[value]!!
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

Thank to @mfulton26 i simplified my code:

```
enum class TaskAction constructor(val value: String) {
    ARCHIVE("Archive"), UN_FLAG("Un flag"), FLAG("Flag"), REDO("Redo"),
    READY("Ready"), EDIT("Edit"), DND("dnd"), DELETE("Delete"),
    IN_PROGRESS("In progress"), DONE("Done");

    companion object {
        private val lookup = values().associateBy(TaskAction::value)
        fun fromValue(value: String):TaskAction = requireNotNull(lookup[value]) { "No TaskAction with value $value" }
    }
}
```

I even reduce the code to with the help of @marstran:

```
companion object {
    fun from(search: String): TaskAction =  requireNotNull(values().find { it.value == search }) { "No TaskAction with value $search" }
}
```

Comment: 1.  `fromValue` might be a better name than `getFromValue`.
2.  `lookup` can be initialized simply as `private val lookup = values().associateBy(TaskAction::value)`.
3.  You might want to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead of a `KotlinNullPointerException`. e.g. `return requireNotNull(lookup[value]) { "No TaskAction with value $value" }`.