# Java Lookup Enum By String Value

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum which is just

```
public enum Blah {
    A, B, C, D
}
```

and I would like to find the enum value of a string, for example "A" which would be **Blah.A**. How would it be possible to do this?

Is the `Enum.valueOf()` the method I need? If so, how would I use this?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080904/how-can-i-lookup-a-java-enum-from-its-string-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I lookup a Java enum from its String value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080904/how-can-i-lookup-a-java-enum-from-its-string-value)

Comment: Please try to search the solution before posting on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Blah.valueOf("A")` which will give you `Blah.A`.

The parameter you are passing in the `valueOf` method should match one of the `Enum` otherwise it will throw in exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Blah blahValueOf(String k) {
    for (Blah c : Blah.values()) {
        if (c.getLabel().toUpperCase().equals(k.toUpperCase())) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can write this method in order to find the `Blah.valueOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use .valueOf method.
for example

```
public class EnumLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            DemoEnum value = DemoEnum.valueOf("A");
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
    enum DemoEnum{
        A,B,C;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the value of Enum class you should go with `valueOf` Method.

`valueOf(argument)` -> Will return the Enum values specific to argument.

`System.out.println(Blah.valueOf("A"));`

Remember one point if the argument were not present in Enum class, you will face **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant**