# How to use Switch and Enum Parameters (Not ENUM VALUE) in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, enums, switch-statement

I have switch case with 50 String checks in case as given below:

```
switch(str){
  case "Employee number":
    //setter
    break;
}
```

I want to put them in Enum with description as given below:

```
enum myenum{
        EMPLOYEE_NUMBER("Employee number"),
        FIRST_NAME("First name");   

        private String desc;
        private myenum(String desc) {
            this.setDesc(desc);
        }
        public String getDesc() {
            return desc;
        }
        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            this.desc = desc;
        }

    }
```

Now, From Source i am getting String "Employee Number" and i want to write switch case in such a way that we can compare description of enum with incoming string input in Case.

I tried some methods in enum

```
myenum.valueOf(a); // This return enum value but not parameter
myenum.values // This is array which is also not useful here
```

Kindly suggest how it is achievable in Enum? I am using Java 8

and also suggest Is enum right choice here? or shall i create Static string class with all 50 values or any other best wayout?

Comment: @Tim: Kindly don't mark it duplicate. Neither that question and nor any of answer covers anything related to enum parameter. Kindly go through question please. I have already gone through some of threads and none of them covering this aspect.

Comment: Have you gone through this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080912/869736

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first get the `MyEnum` instance from `String str` and then use `switch` by `MyEnum`, like below:

```
enum MyEnum {
    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER("Employee number"),
    FIRST_NAME("First name");

    private String desc;

    MyEnum(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public static Optional<MyEnum> fromDesc(String desc) {
        return Stream.of(MyEnum.values()).filter(myEnum -> myEnum.getDesc().equals(desc)).findFirst();
    }

}
```

And then in your main code:

```
Optional<MyEnum> maybeMyEnum = MyEnum.fromDesc(str);
if (maybeMyEnum.isPresent()) {
    switch(maybeMyEnum.get()){
        case EMPLOYEE_NUMBER:
            //setter
            break;
    }
}
```

---

**UPD 1:**
As @Ole V.V. - stated in a comment, using `Optional.get()` and `Optional.isPresent()` is not a best practice - the idea is - you have to defer getting value out of `Optional` as much as possible. Also `Optional.get()` violates `getter` contract:

> Optional.get() is an "attractive nuisance" and is too tempting for programmers, leading to frequent errors. People don't expect a getter to throw an exception.

From [JDK-8140281 : (opt) add no-arg orElseThrow() as preferred alternative to get()](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8140281)

So given that, you can rewrite your code as:

```
...
MyEnum.fromDesc(str)
    .ifPresent(SomeClass::methodWithSwitchStatement);
...
class SomeClass {
    public static void methodWithSwitchStatement(MyEnum myEnum) {
        switch(myEnum){
            case EMPLOYEE_NUMBER:
               //setter
               break;
        }
    }
}
...
```

*The names in the above code are just for examples - you shouldn't use such names in your project.*

---

**UPD 2:**
Here is the version of `MyEnum` with caching:

```
enum MyEnum {
    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER("Employee number"),
    FIRST_NAME("First name");

    private static final Map<String, MyEnum> cacheByDesc;
    static {
        cacheByDesc = Stream.of(MyEnum.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(MyEnum::getDesc, e -> e));
    }

    private String desc;

    MyEnum(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public static Optional<MyEnum> fromDesc(String desc) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(desc)
                .map(cacheByDesc::get);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Vusal. Let me try this. Any performance overhead, if already calculated?

Comment: You can build some `Map` from `MyEnum.values()` and reduce runtime complexity of `fromDesc` from `O(n)` to `O(1)` - where `n` - is the number of entries in `MyEnum`, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080904/how-can-i-lookup-a-java-enum-from-its-string-value/1080912#1080912

Comment: Thanks. Working fine both way. I hope my lead will not say to use simple 50 Strings only in case or standard old way i.e static constant in file. :)

Comment: More conventional (and a bit shorter): `maybeMyEnum.ifPresent(mEnum -> { switch (mEnum) { /* … */ } });`. Rule of thumb: rarely use `isPresent` and `get`, they are low-level.

Comment: Yeah, you can add a `Map` from string to enum constant, or you implement `fromDesc` with a `switch` statement…

Comment: @Vusal: Can you also bring Map to this answer which is somewhere in another link according to your example? It will make it full fledged answer too