# Set enum value using attribute

Tags: java, enums

I would like to know if it's possible to set an enum's value by specifying one of its attributes. 
E.g. suppose that I have the following enum:

```
public enum Example
    {
    EXONE("Exone", 1), EXTWO("Extwo", 3);
    private final String type;
    private final int number;


    Example(String type,int number)
        {
        this.type = type;
        this.number = number
        }

    public String getType()
        {
        return this.type;
        }

    public int getNumber()
        {
        return number;
        }
    }
```

Now assume that I would like to get the value `EXTWO` and store it inside a variable. Is it possible to do this by providing a String equal to the `type`-attribute? Something like:

```
String attribute = "Extwo";
Example ex_1 = Example.attribute
```

The above lines obviously will not work but I hope they clarify what I would like to do. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080904/how-can-i-lookup-a-java-enum-from-its-string-value . See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody for the links! I was able to solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use valueOf() method associated with every enum,

```
Example ex_1 = Example.valueOf(attribute.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Thanks! valueOf() works nicely!