# Convert a String to an Enum?

Tags: java, enums

Hi I'm having trouble trying to generalize a function I've written for an specific enum:

```
public static enum InstrumentType {
    SPOT {
        public String toString() {
            return "MKP";
        }
    },
    VOLATILITY {
        public String toString() {
            return "VOL";
        }
    };

    public static InstrumentType parseXML(String value) {
        InstrumentType ret = InstrumentType.SPOT;

        for(InstrumentType instrumentType : values()) {
            if(instrumentType.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                ret = instrumentType;
                break;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

I wish to add a new parameter to the function that will represent any enum. I know I'm supposed to use templates but I can't use the function "values()" then inside the function code.
Basicly what I want is a valueOf function that uses the toString() value I've defined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just name your enums MKP and VOL, that way you get the string parsing for free?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-enum-converting-string-to-enum

Comment: I agree, but I also want it to choose a default value and I dont want the name of the ENUM be dependant on the string it prints.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try a much cleaner way of writing your enum:

```
public static enum InstrumentType {

    SPOT("MKP"),
    VOLATILITY("VOL");

    private final String name;

    InstrumentType(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public static InstrumentType getValue(String s)
    {
        for (InstrumentType t : InstrumentType.values())
        {
            if (t.toString().equals(s))
                return t;
        }
        return SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE;
    }
}
```

This also solves your problem of String -> Enum. It might be cleaner to just use the three-letter acronyms as the enum name, but in the case you will need to make the `getValue()` decision according to other parameters, this is the right way to go.

Comment: That is a neater way to overwrite the toString method, thanks.

Comment: +1 We're naturally allergic to linear searches, so we tend not to realize that in small and medium enums it's never really going to cost that much.

Comment: Just wanted to call attention (since I missed it at first) to the fact that getValue is intentionally named differently from the static valueOf you get for free.  valueOf cannot be overridden.

Comment: FWLIW, I'd use a name a little more different from "toValue" - there's no way to "turn off" toValue, and one's too likely to use the wrong one without noticing.  Even just "getValueOf" would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Enums can implement interfaces, so you could define one with a values() method and then use that as your parameter type.

But as the commenter said, it would probably be easier if you named your enums MKP, VOL etc