# Java enumerations with database support best practices

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, enums

I have already looked around for some answers, but they do not satisfy me enough. I hope this is not duplicated.

I have an application with data that should be constant. This data can be modified later, so my current approach was using a separate table with this constants, which is referenced from other tables. This table has a column ID and the column Value for instance. And this table is represented by a Java object with ID and Value.

My problem comes when I want to compare this constants. Comparing using it's ID seems ugly to me, so I though to use enums to compare between them. But this seems awkward because I would be using an ENUM within a class that is used as a "Type". So I was thinking also in the @enumerated annotation from JPA...but honestly, I do not see the best way to do that. The thing I'm sure is that I definitely want -somehow- this constant data stored in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

On the top of my head I can think about the following approaches.

1. Create `enum` and map its name to DB. This approach is simple and will work. Its disadvantage is that too many strings in DB. So, if enum element names is being changed you have to fix the DB. The strings occupy space. And such field requires indexing if you want to use it into query criteria.
2. Create `enum` and map its ordinal to DB. This is simple too but DB requires maintenance even one order of enum elements are changed. And DB data is less readable.

Both #1 and #2 have common disadvantage: actually data is stored twice: once hard-coded as an enum. Twice in DB. If you have to modify the data you have to do this in 2 places. The modifications must be done during development because the `enum` must be re-compiled.

However there is other [solution](http://java.dzone.com/articles/enum-tricks-dynamic-enums) that offers so called "dynamic enums". Take a look. Probably this solution will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Data that can be modified later, is no longer constant but variable ... ;-)

Anyway: if the list of possible values can change over time, I see no problem in using Enums and the @enumerated JPA annotation.

If the values themselves can change, you will need some kind of name/value mapping, in order to avoid using ID's for comparing. You could also add "properties" to Enums, which you can use for the variable part of your data. That way, only the names of the Enums will be stored as constant Strings in the database (as an identifier) and the "value" can change in your code.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use String fields to store your enums into the database table and just wrap them on the way back out for use by other objects.

Such as one of the following:

[Convert a String to an Enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818712/convert-a-string-to-an-enum)

http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/01/3-ways-to-serialize-java-enums/