# Java String to enum

Tags: java, enums

I have this class constructor `AppData(Map params, Operations operation)`
where **Operations** is

```
public enum Operations 
{
create,update,delete,view,compare
}
```

How can I instantiate AppData with parameters constructor?

for the map parameter its fine i get that from servlet, (req.getParameterMap())
but the main problem for me is knowing the operation type, which also comes from the map parameter, So in order to do this `AppData data=new AppData(req.getParameterMap(),op);` what shall I assign to `op` or what shall an `op` type be?

Note: I can get the String `create` , `update` ... from `req.getParameterMap()` by using iterator and Map.Entry object.getKey() and Value

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-enum-converting-string-to-enum ?

Comment: enums should be given names with capital letters: `CREATE` instead of `create` and so on. I suggest a refactoring to implement the Java naming conventions (increases readability).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're starting with a string (e.g., `"update"`), you can use [`Enum.valueOf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29). Your `Operations` enum will inherit a form of that, so:

```
Operations op = Operations.valueOf(theString);
```

...or use the one from `Enum`, though you'd really only have to do this if you don't have direct, compile-time access to `Operations`. I think you do have compile-time access, so use the above. But for completeness:

```
Object op = Enum.valueOf(Class.forName("Operations"), theString);
```

Comment: is it, Enum.valueOf("update") ? Also, I need to store "update" in some var first.

Comment: @Abhishek: I've shown both the usual forms. If you have compile-time access to `Operations`, use `Operations.valueOf(theString);` If not, use `Enum.valueOf` and pass in the `Class` object of the enum and the string.