# Built in parsing of a string to a Scala case object?

Tags: parsing, scala

Is there any way to automatically parse a case object from a string, in Scala? Using some built in / automatically generated Scala function?

For example, I have these case objects:  (*please note* that there's a sealed parent class)

```
abstract sealed class FlagReason

case object Spam extends FlagReason
case object Illegal extends FlagReason
case object CopyrightViolation extends FlagReason
case object Other extends FlagReason
```

and I'm wondering if there's some automatically generated function that works like:

`FlagReason.fromString(value: String): FlagReason`

where `FlagReason("Spam")` would return the `Spam` case object.

If there were, then I need not write my own -- which I've done:

```
object FlagReason {
  def fromString(value: String): FlagReason = value match {
    case "Spam" => Spam
    case "Illegal" => Illegal
    case "CopyrightViolation" => CopyrightViolation
    case "Other" => Other
  }
}
```

*Background*: I'm converting my case objects to strings that I use as radio button values in a html form. I'm converting the selected value back to a case object, when I handle the submitted form.

*Related info*: This is actually possible with Java enums, see e.g. this StackOverflow question: [Lookup enum by string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-enum-converting-string-to-enum)

((I don't think I'm looking for Scala's Parser Combinators. I suppose that were I to use them I'd still need to define the parsing rules myself, rather than having built in "automatic" string to case object conversion))

Comment: Note, that your link shows C# enums. Btw, can you provide a scenario, where you actually need such a feature?

Comment: @agilesteel: I've fixed the link now, thanks. I also added some info on why I do that kind of conversion.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, no such method is automatically generated. You will have to write your own `fromString` method. Note that you can write it more compactly as follows:

```
object FlagReason {
  def fromString(value: String): Option[FlagReason] = {
    Vector(Spam, Illegal, CopyRightViolation, Other).find(_.toString == value)
  }
}
```

Alternatively you may consider using [`scala.Enumeration`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration) which does provide this facility.

```
object FlagReason extends Enumeration {
  val Spam, Illegal, CopyRightViolation, Other = Value
}
```

Then you can obtain the particular enum value with `FlagReason withName "<name>"`, or safely as an `Option` with `Try(FlagReason withName "<name>").toOption`.

Comment: Thanks, something like `extends Enumeration` was kind of what I was hoping for :-)

Answer (score 4):

As [missingfaktor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7530331/549102) points out, `FlagReason withName "<name>"` should do what you need. But if `<name>` is not a valid name, it will throw an exception. So, a slightly safer way to handle this when you are not sure if the name is valid is to use `Option[FlagReason]`:

```
scala> def parse(name: String) = FlagReason.values.find(_.toString == name)
parse: (name: String)Option[FlagReason.Value]

scala> parse("Spam")
res0: Option[FlagReason.Value] = Some(Spam)

scala> parse("NonExisting")
res1: Option[FlagReason.Value] = None
```