# Convert String to Enum?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - Convert String to enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-convert-string-to-enum)

I have a method that uses an enum:

```
mymethod(AnotherClass.MyEnum.PassedEnum);
```

And I want to nest this within a class that receives a String which becomes MyEnum:

```
public static void method(String toPass){

 mymethod(AnotherClass.toPass.PassedEnum);

}
```

The passed variable has to be a String but I need to convert it to a Enum to pass to AnotherClass?

TIA

Comment: Thanks to all just what was needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `AnotherClass.MyEnum.valueOf(toPass)`

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean like ...

```
MyEnum e = MyEnum.valueOf(text);
```

or

```
MyEnum e = Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, text);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the static factory method [`Enum.valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this in the body of `method`:

```
AnotherClass.toPass.PassedEnum.valueOf(toPass);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enum.valueOf(Class<...>, String)` to convert a string to the corresponding enum instance:

```
MyEnum value = Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, "ENUM_VALUE");
```

If the string contains a value that does not exist as an enum constant, this method throws `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void method(String toPass){

 mymethod(AnotherClass.MyEnum.valueOf(toPass));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the static method `Enum.valueOf` to convert a string to a Enum value:

```
public static void method(String toPass)
{
    AnotherClass.MyEnum eval = Enum.valueOf(AnotherClass.MyEnum.class,toPass);
    mymethod(eval);
}
```