# Many enums with same functionality?

Tags: java, enums

I'd like to create a few enums such as described in this answer:
[Lookup enum by string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-convert-string-to-enum/2965252#2965252)

(I.e an enum that has a toString() and a name which is different to the enum itself)

Is there any way I can reuse this functionality without having to reimplement it in each enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass in the list of possible values, then you can do it without so much as depending upon the type being an `enum`.

```
public static <T> T findByString(T[] values, String toString) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(toString);
    for (T t : values) {
        if (toString.equals(t.toString())) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Call with:

```
Blah blah = SomeClass.findByString(Blah.values(), str);
```

Rather than calling `Blah.values()` every time, you could use put it in an object, which could be passed around and used generically. Perhaps other methods added later.

```
public interface ByString<T> { // Choose a better name.
    T find(String toString);
}
[...]
    private static final ByString<Blah> blahs = byString(Blah.values());
[...]
    public static <T> ByString<T> byString(T[] values) {
        final T[] valuesCopy = values.clone();
        return new ByString<T>() {
            public T find(String toString) {
                return SomeClass.findByString(valuesCopy, toString);
            }
        };
    }
[...]
```

Call with:

```
Blah blah = blahs.find(str);
```

In fact, you might want to optimise that. Do the `toString`ing once, and use a map.

```
    public static <T> ByString<T> byString(T[] values) {
        final Map<String,T> byToStrings = new HashMap<>(
            (int)(values.length/0.75f)+1 // Doesn't HashMap construction suck.
        );
        for (T value : values) {
            byToStrings.put(values.toString(), value);
        }
        return new ByString<T>() {
            public T find(String toString) {
                T value = byToStrings.get(toString);
                if (value == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
                return value;
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can get away from the "adding a field and a property" in each enum. You can make your `fromText` method delegate to a common method though, if you create an interface for that property, and pass either `values()` or (better) an `EnumSet`. (Better: write a method to create a case-insensitive `Map`, and call that once in each enum, storing the result  in a static variable.)

Comment: Thinking it might be simpler to just take away "named" enums entirely! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many enums which share the same functionality I would either.

- Use one enum since they have a lot in common.
- Use a helper method each enum can call.

Java 8 will make this simpler with virtual extensions. It will allow you to define a default implementation on the interface (which has to be a helper/static method)