# Can this code be written in a better and more flexible way?

Tags: java, oop

Please see the code below . Here based on the String constants , I am instantiating different types of component classes . Now there are atleast 15 different types of String constants . So if I follow this pattern there will be 15 different cases and those many if -else blocks . Is there a better way of doing this ? I want to have the flexibility of being able to add and delete cases by doing the minimum possible code change.

```
public UIComponent initCellEditor(String editorType) {
        UIComponent editControl = null;
        if ("TbComboBoxCellType".equals(editorType)) {
          editControl = new WebListEntryField();
          editControl.setId("ComboBox");
        } else if ("TbStringCellType".equals(editorType)) {
          editControl = new WebInputEntryField();
          editControl.setId("String");
        } else if ("TbDateCellType".equals(editorType)) {
          editControl = new WebDateEntryField();
          editControl.setId("Date");
        } else if ("TbDateTimeCellType".equals(editorType)) {
          editControl = new WebDateTimeEntryField();
          editControl.setId("DateTime");
        } else {
          //default editor is allways a text input
          editControl = new WebInputEntryField();
          editControl.setId("Input");
        }
        return editControl;
      }
```

P.S: We are using JDK 6 . So can't use switch on String feature.

Comment: use a `switch`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Switch on string is only possible in Java 7 and later. If it has to be Strings here, you could switch on their hash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could transform those string constants to Enums, and add a builder method on the enum, for example

```
public enum CellType {
      TbComboBox {
         @Override
         public UIComponent newComponent() {
            return new xxx();
         }
      },
      TbDate {
         @Override
         public UIComponent newComponent() {
            return new xxx();
         }
      }

      public abstract UIComponent newComponent();
}
```

The beauty of this approach is that it replaces `IFs` with polymorphism (which in my opnion is very OO).

---

Sorry, I just realised that you have a default type (the last else in your code), so you might need to add an `if` somewhere :(.

Comment: I still have to have  the call to initCellEditor  . So what will the method initCellEditor look like with this approach ? Also can I have this enum as a static nested class inside  another public class?

Comment: You would need to convert `editorType` from string to an Enum everywhere. It's usually a bad practice to represent types as strings. If you do this, then `initCellEditor` disappears completely. Please bear in mind that this solution might not be right for you, I've done things like this in the past and it worked for me.

Comment: Geek! I forgot to say, that this solution also abides by the [Open/Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)! :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe: Use a `Map`.  This approach has the possible advantage of working even if you create new classes, as long as you inject the new type into the `Map`.  It's got a dependency injection flavor to it.

```
package cruft;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * UIComponentFactory description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 9/18/12 5:48 AM
 */
public class UIComponentFactory {
    Map<String, UIComponent> uiComponentMap;
    Map<String, String> uiIdMap;

    public UIComponentFactory(Map<String, UIComponent> uiComponentMap, Map<String, String> uiIdMap) {
        this.uiComponentMap = new HashMap<String, UIComponent>(uiComponentMap);
        this.uiIdMap = new HashMap<String, UIComponent>(uiIdMap);
    }

    public UIComponent initCellEditor(String editorType) {
        UIComponent editControl = null;
        editControl = this.uiComponentMap.get(editorType);
        if (editControl != null) {
            editControl.setId(this.uiIdMap.get(editorType));
        } else {
            editControl = new WebInputEntryField();
            editControl.setId("Input");
        }
        return editControl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look again, Matt.  I pass in editorType and I use it as the key to the Map when I look up the returned value.  Did you even read the code?

Comment: I don't really care either way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an enum:

```
public static enum Editor {

    TB_COMBOBOX_CELL("tbComboBoxCellType", "ComboBox") {
        public UIComponent getComponent() {
            return new WebListEntryField();
        }
    },
    TB_STRING_CELL("TbStringCellType", "String") {
        //etc
    };
    private final String type;
    private final String id;

    private Editor(String type, String id) {
        this.type = type;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public abstract UIComponent getComponent();
    private static Map<String, Editor> types = new HashMap<String, Editor>();

    static {
        for (Editor e : Editor.values()) {
            types.put(e.getType(), e);
        }
    }

    public static Editor getEditor(String type) {
        Editor e = types.get(type);
        if (e == null) return Editor.DEFAULT_EDITOR;
        return e;
    }
}
```

Then your method becomes:

```
public UIComponent initCellEditor(String editorType) {
    Editor e = Editor.getEditor(editorType);
    UIComponent editControl = e.getComponent();
    editControl.setId(e.getId());
    return editControl;
}
```

Comment: how to define Editor.DEFAULT_EDITOR ?

Comment: @Geek just add a `DEFAULT_EDITOR` to your enum list, with the proper `getComponent` method...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Factory` pattern to create objects depending on their types. For e.g.:

Create a factory class something like this:

```
public class UIComponentFactory {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UIComponentFactory.class);

    private static UIComponentFactory instance;

    private static final LinkedHashMap<String, Class> COMPONENTS_MAP = new LinkedHashMap<String, Class>() {{
        put("TbComboBoxCellType", WebListEntryField.class);
        put("TbStringCellType", WebInputEntryField.class);
        put("TbDateCellType", WebDateEntryField.class);
    }};

    private UIComponentFactory() {
    }

    public UIComponent createUIComponent(String type) {
        Class componentClass = COMPONENTS_MAP.get(type);
        Object componentObject = null;
        if (componentClass != null) {
            try {
                componentObject = componentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                LOGGER.error("Instantiation exception occurred", ex);
                throw new SystemException("Instantiation exception occurred", ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                LOGGER.error("Illegal access exception occurred", ex);
                throw new SystemException("Illegal access exception occurred", ex);
            }
        }
        return (UIComponent) componentObject;
    }

    public static UIComponentFactory getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new UIComponentFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Then to create your component use:

```
UIComponentFactory factory = UIComponentFactory.getInstance();
UIComponent component = factory.createUIComponent("yourComponentType");
```

This would be a more efficient way then using `if else` statements.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest: Don't change anything. There are a couple of options to refactor this code, but IMHO they won't improve the readability of your code. Stick with `if`, it's not as evil as they want you to believe...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an enum based approach as follows:

```
enum EditorType {
    TbComboBoxCellType(WebListEntryField.class, "ComboBox"),
    TbStringCellType(WebInputEntryField.class, "String"),
    TbDateCellType(WebDateEntryField.class, "Date"),
    TbDateTimeCellType(WebDateTimeEntryField.class, "DateTime"),
    Generic(WebInputEntryField.class, "Input");

    private final Class<? extends UIComponent> componentType;
    private final String id;

    private EditorType(Class<? extends UIComponent> componentType, String id) {
        this.componentType = componentType;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static UIComponent createComponent(String editorType) {
        EditorType type;
        try {
            type = valueOf(editorType)
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            type = Generic;
        }
        return type.createComponent();
    }

    public UIComponent createComponent() {
        try {
            UIComponent component = componentType.newInstance();
            component.setId(id);
            return component;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not create `new WebListEntryField();` or other `xxEntryField()` each time. Create a private field and return the same instance.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a Enum to capture all

> CellTypes

and another or the same enum to get the Ids
and use that Enum to compare the input coming in.

Answer (score 0):

Use switch on enums. Change `String editorType` to emum type. If this is impossible, convert `editorType` to enum as in [following SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-convert-string-to-enum).

Answer (score 0):

you can use enum based comparison. Create different enum for different input type and then use switch case.

EditorType.java

```
public enum EditorType {
  COMBO_CELL_TYPE("TbComboBoxCellType"),
  STRING_CELL_TYPE("TbStringCellType"),
  DATE_CELL_TYPE("TbDateCellType"),
  TIME_CELL_TYPE("TbDateCellType"),
  INPUT_CELL_TYPE("TbInputCellType");

  public String value;

  private EditorType(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

}
```

While compare use switch statement.

```
public UIComponent initCellEditor(EditorType editorType) {
  UIComponent editControl = null;

  switch (editorType) {
    case COMBO_CELL_TYPE:
      // logic here
      break;

    case STRING_CELL_TYPE:

      break;

    case DATE_CELL_TYPE:

      break;

    case TIME_CELL_TYPE:

      break;

    default:
      // default logic
  }
}
```