# How to match and switch Strings against enums?

Tags: java, enums

I want to transform a String into an enum. But how?

```
class Letter {
    A, B, C
}

String letter = "A";
switch (letter) {
    case Letter.A: //cannot convert from Letter to String
    case Letter.A.toString(): //case expressions must be constant expressions
    case Letter.C.name(): //case expressions must be constant expressions
    default:
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-convert-string-to-enum

is this what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First the `Letter` must be an enum:

```
enum Letter {
    A, B, C
}

Letter letter = Letter.valueOf("A")
// and just switch
switch (letter) {
    case A:
    case B:
    case C:
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
String letter = "A";
switch (Letter.valueOf(letter)) {
    case A: // No problem!
    case B:
    case C:
    default:
}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/aL0dOR).

Comment: This will not work I guess.

Comment: We can't use qualified name of enum constants in cases. They have to be unqualified names. So that should be `case A:`.

Answer (score 2):

Make that enum first instead of Class
Replace to this

```
Letter obj = Letter.valueOf(letter);
switch (obj) {
    case A: //cannot convert from Letter to String
    case B: //case expressions must be constant expressions
    case C: //case expressions must be constant expressions
    default:
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

```
Letter l = Letter.valueOf("A");
```

or

```
Letter l = Enum.valueOf(Letter.class, "A");

switch (l) {
    case A:
    case B:
    case C:
    default:
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string don't match with some constant in the enum, throws an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant`. Try with the next:

```
class Letter {
    A, B, C;
    public static Letter fromString(String str) {
    if (str != null) {
      for (Letter l : Letter.values()) {
        if (l.toString().equals(str)) {
            return l;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```