# how to get the ENUM from the string value - JAVA

Tags: java, enums

I am new to java and now I am trying to see if its possible to get ENUM from the string value it is assigned.

Consider for example i have this below ENUM ( i have corrected to give complete structure)

```
public enum Signal{
    RED("stop"), GREEN("start"), ORANGE("slow down");

    private String value;

    private Signal(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to determine ENUM if i have the value which is assigned to it. That is is possible to get RED if i have "stop"

When i searched in internet the "valueof" is discussed which is not what i need as it helps the different purpose. Any reference would be greatly appreciated as well.
Thank you for reading!!

Comment: You'll have to write your own method.

Comment: See the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-convert-string-to-enum).

Comment: Your enum definition is invalid; your values all use a constructor that you have not defined.

Comment: I dint give the full ENUm structure i tried. Inlcuded the full definition above. Is this still in-correct with the way i have defined my enum?

Comment: The general pattern for this is to have a static `Map` - in your case Map<String, Signal> - which you initialize in a static block inside the enum class. In that map you put each enum value with with as key the the value you pass to the constructor - or simply call getValue() - . Then finally have a static method for retrieving your values, for example: `Signal getByValue(String)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public enum Signal{
  ...

  public static Signal byValue(String value) {
    Singal[] signales = Signal.getEnumConstants();
    for (Signal s:signals) {
       if (s.getValue().equals(value) {
         return s;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Method shouldn't be static?

Comment: byValue should be static

Comment: I would also say using values() instead of getEnumConstants() is neater.

Comment: I think the idea is more important then the elegance of the implementation ;)