# Casting string to enum after getting string by column from database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, enums

I have `Condition` entity and have one attribute `ConditionType` who have two enums, medical and behavioral, that I want to set after getting `CONDITION_NAME` from SQL Server.

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private List<Condition> getConditions(String patientId, Date runDate) {
    // TODO

    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);  
    String sql = "select patient_id,condition_name from patient_condition, cpl_manage_condition"
    + " where patient_condition.condition_id = cpl_manage_condition.condition_id";

    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = template.queryForList(sql);
    List<Condition> conditions = new ArrayList<Condition>();

    for (Map row: rows) {
        Condition condition = new Condition();

        //getting error
        condition.setType((ConditionType)((String)row.get("CONDITION_NAME")));

        conditions.add(condition);
    }

    return conditions;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your error is

```
condition.setType((ConditionType)((String)row.get("CONDITION_NAME")));
```

And should be

```
condition.setType(ConditionType.valueOf(row.get("CONDITION_NAME").toString()));
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/604424/2970947).

Comment: how to set in separately in medical and behavioral condition public enum ConditionType {
    MEDICAL, BEHAVIORAL
}

Comment: @user3865046 Why did you post that as a comment here? You can use the String(s) "MEDICAL" and "BEHAVIORAL" with my answer above.

Comment: i m new here don't know where to post ....i m getting error just like different conditions like asthma, diabetic etc //error// No enum constant com.mp.model.ConditionType.Asthama // i m using couchbase db (no sql db)

Comment: Sounds like you need to delete your version of `ConditionType` and use the version from `com.mp.model.ConditionType`. If that's you, then your enum is missing valid values. It's not a class. You might need one.

Answer (score 2):

If `ConditionType` is an `enum`, you can use `ConditionType.valueOf(String)` to convert a `String` value to that type. Notice you should take care of `null` and invalid arguments then.