# How to return value by ternary condition in a stream?

Tags: java, enums, java-8, java-stream

I want to return a value of a stream based on a condition. Take the following as an example only, where I want to map any apple to `Food.APPLE`:

```
public enum Food {
    APPLE, APPLE2, APPLE3, BANANA, PINEAPPLE, CUCUMBER;

    private static final Food[] APPLES = new Food[] {APPLE, APPLE2, APPLE3};

    //java7
    public Food fromValue(String value) {
        for (Food type : Food.values()) {
            if (type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return ArrayUtils.contains(APPLES, type) ? APPLE : type;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //java8: how to include the array check for APPLES?
    public Food fromValue(String value) {
        return Arrays.stream(Food.values()).
            filter(type -> type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

How can I include the ternary condition in a stream?

Comment: Well you could use a `map` with the condition inside.

Comment: @AlexisC. Ok thanks, you probably mean `.map(type -> ArrayUtils.contains(APPLES, type) ? APPLE : type)`? If so, and if that's the best solution, you could add it as an answer.

Comment: And what about something like `private static final HashSet<String> APPLES = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("apple", "apple2", "apple3"));` and `public static Food fromValue(String value) {
        return APPLES.contains(value.toLowerCase()) ? APPLE : null;
    }` ? Constant time in complexity and less code to write.

Comment: Ah it's not exactly the same. But your problem could be reduced to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807232/finding-enum-value-with-java-8-stream-api/27807324#27807324. My suggestion would be to use a map there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
import static java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry;

...

enum Food {
    APPLE, APPLE2, APPLE3, BANANA, PINEAPPLE, CUCUMBER;

    private static final Map<String, Food> MAP = Stream.concat(
                Stream.of(APPLE, APPLE2, APPLE3).map(e -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.name().toLowerCase(), APPLE)),
                Stream.of(BANANA, PINEAPPLE, CUCUMBER).map(e -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.name().toLowerCase(), e)))
            .collect(toMap(SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey, SimpleImmutableEntry::getValue));

    public static Food fromValue(String value) {
        return MAP.get(value.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

The lookup in the map will be `O(1)`.

Comment: You don’t need `getOrDefault` to get a null value. You can simply call `get()` as it’s the contract of the ordinary `Map.get` method to return `null` if there is no mapping. Btw. using lowercase might be sufficient for ASCII characters but isn’t a general solution for case insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 2):

As Alexis suggested, you can use a map operation

```
public Food fromValue_v8(String value) {
    return Arrays.stream(Food.values())
        .filter(type-> type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
        .map(type -> ArrayUtils.contains(APPLES, type) ? APPLE : type)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special to the ternary operator. So you can simply add this mapping operation to the `Stream`

```
public Food fromValue(String value) {
    return Arrays.stream(Food.values())
        .filter(type -> type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
        .map(type -> ArrayUtils.contains(APPLES, type)? APPLE: type)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
}
```

However, neither of these linear searches is really necessary. Use a `Map`:

```
public enum Food {
    APPLE, APPLE2, APPLE3, BANANA, PINEAPPLE, CUCUMBER;

    private static final Map<String,Food> MAP
        = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    static {
       EnumSet<Food> apples=EnumSet.of(APPLE, APPLE2, APPLE3);
       apples.forEach(apple->MAP.put(apple.name(), APPLE));
       EnumSet.complementOf(apples).forEach(e->MAP.put(e.name(), e));
    }
    public static Food fromValue(String value) {
        return MAP.get(value);
    }
}
```

It will perform a case insensitive lookup as desired and it is initialized to return the `APPLE` substitute in the first place so no additional comparison is required.

Answer (score 2):

According to previous answers, in particular from @Alexis I wrote some code to check booth approach (from Java 7 and Java 8). Maybe this can be useful for new users on Java 8.

So, I've made some changes in original answer. First of all, I put some unit test and I added two *wrapping* methods **verifyNames()** and **contains()**. Second, we can use a *default behavior* when unexpected action occurs, in this case, when the **appleApproachTwo.fromValueJava8()** was called with **null** or an **not existing** enum value.

Finally, the last change uses the potential uses for **java.util.Optional** objects. In this case, we can protect the environment to crash due to inconsistency to null objects. There are more discussion about Default Values, Optional and orElse() method at [Default Values and Actions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

```
    public enum Food {
    APPLE, APPLE2, APPLE3, BANANA, PINEAPPLE, CUCUMBER, NONE;

    private static final Food[] APPLES = new Food[] {APPLE, APPLE2, APPLE3};

    // approach one
    // java7: conventional use
    public Food fromValueJava7(String value) {
        for (Food type : Food.values()) {
            if (verifyNames(type, value)) {
                return contains(Food.APPLES, type) ? Food.APPLE : type;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    // approach two
    // java8: how to include the array check for APPLES?
    public Food fromValueJava8(String value) {
        return Arrays.stream(Food.values())
                .filter(type-> verifyNames(type, value))
                .map(type -> contains(Food.APPLES, type) ? Food.APPLE : type)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(Food.NONE);
    }

    private boolean contains(Food[] apples, Food type) {
        return ArrayUtils.contains(apples, type);
    }

    private boolean verifyNames(Food type,String other) {
        return type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(other);
    }
    }

    //   FoodTest
    //   
    public class FoodTest {
    @Test
    public void foodTest(){
        Food appleApproachOne  = Food.APPLE;

        // from approach one
        assertEquals( appleApproachOne.fromValueJava7("APPLE"),   Food.APPLE);
        assertEquals( appleApproachOne.fromValueJava7("APPLE2"),  Food.APPLE);
        assertEquals( appleApproachOne.fromValueJava7("APPLE3"),  Food.APPLE);
        assertEquals( appleApproachOne.fromValueJava7("apple3"),  Food.APPLE);
        assertNull  ( appleApproachOne.fromValueJava7("apple4") );
        assertNull  ( appleApproachOne.fromValueJava7(null) );

        Food appleApproachTwo  = Food.APPLE;

        //from approach two
        assertEquals( appleApproachTwo.fromValueJava8("APPLE"),   Food.APPLE);
        assertEquals( appleApproachTwo.fromValueJava8("APPLE2"),  Food.APPLE);
        assertEquals( appleApproachTwo.fromValueJava8("APPLE3"),  Food.APPLE);
        assertEquals( appleApproachTwo.fromValueJava8("apple3"),  Food.APPLE);
        assertEquals( appleApproachOne.fromValueJava8("apple4"),  Food.NONE);
        assertEquals( appleApproachTwo.fromValueJava8(null),      Food.NONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, using a `Map` would be better:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TernaryCondition {

    public enum Food {
        APPLE, APPLE2, APPLE3, BANANA, PINEAPPLE, CUCUMBER;

        private static final EnumSet<Food> APPLES = EnumSet.of(APPLE, APPLE2, APPLE3);

        private static final Map<String, Food> MAP = Stream.of(
            Food.values()).collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                f -> f.name().toLowerCase(), 
                f -> APPLES.contains(f) ? APPLE : f));

        public static Food fromValue(String value) {
            return MAP.get(value.toLowerCase());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Food f = Food.fromValue("apple2");

        System.out.println(f); // APPLE
    }
}
```

I'd also make `fromValue()` method `static` and `APPLES` an `EnumSet`. While I realise this answer is very similar to @Holger's, I just wanted to show another approach to build the map.