# How to store enum to map using Java 8 stream API

Tags: java, enums, java-8, java-stream

I have an `enum` with another `enum` as a parameter

```
public enum MyEntity{
   Entity1(EntityType.type1,
    ....


   MyEntity(EntityType type){
     this.entityType = entityType;
   }
}
```

I want to create a method that return the `enum` by type

```
public MyEntity getEntityTypeInfo(EntityType entityType) {
        return lookup.get(entityType);
    }
```

usually I would have written

```
private static final Map<EntityType, EntityTypeInfo> lookup = new HashMap<>();

static {
    for (MyEntity d : MyEntity.values()){
        lookup.put(d.getEntityType(), d);
    }
}
```

What is the best practice to write it with java stream?

Comment: Is your enum called `EntityTypeInfo` or `MyEntity`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess there are some typos in your code (the method should be static in my opinion, your constructor is doing a no-op at the moment), but if I'm following you, you can create a stream from the array of enums and use the `toMap` collector, mapping each enum with its `EntityType` for the keys, and mapping the instance itself as a value:

```
private static final Map<EntityType, EntityTypeInfo> lookup =
    Arrays.stream(EntityTypeInfo.values())
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(EntityTypeInfo::getEntityType, e -> e));
```

The `toMap` collector does not make any guarantee about the map implementation returned (although it's currently a `HashMap`), but you can always use the [overloaded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) variant if you need more control, providing a throwing merger as parameter.

You could also use [another trick with a static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807232/finding-enum-value-with-java-8-stream-api/27807324#27807324), and fill the map in the constructor.

Comment: You can improve this with `Function.identity()` instead of `e -> e` as `Function.identity()` always returns the same function.

Comment: @dustin.schultz `e -> e` is exactly the same, as this lambda expression does not capture values, it will be a singleton that is re-used at each invocation. Furthermore, `Function.identity()` is implemented as `return t -> t;`.

Comment: Ah yes, doesn't capture, so uses singleton. I still think Function.identity() is very-slightly more clear. :)

Comment: @dustin.schultz Matter of taste, I guess. I find `e -> e` really explicit and shorter but everyone has its own preference ;-).

Comment: `Stream.of()` is nicer than `Arrays.stream()` :)

Comment: @aliopi `Stream.of(T... values)` calls `Arrays.stream(values)`, internally..
Using Stream.of(...) would result in an additional array creation because of the varargs (T... values)

Answer (score 5):

```
public enum FibreSpeed {
        a30M( "30Mb Fibre Connection - Broadband Only", 100 ),
        a150M( "150Mb Fibre Connection - Broadband Only", 300 ),
        a1G( "1Gb Fibre Connection - Broadband Only", 500 ),
        b30M( "30Mb Fibre Connection - Broadband & Phone", 700 ),
        b150M( "150Mb Fibre Connection - Broadband & Phone", 900 ),
        b1G( "1Gb Fibre Connection - Broadband & Phone", 1000 );

        public String speed;
        public int    weight;

        FibreSpeed(String speed, int weight) {
            this.speed = speed;
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public static Map<String, Integer> SPEEDS = Stream.of( values() ).collect( Collectors.toMap( k -> k.speed, v -> v.weight ) );
    }
```