# Stream API: create empty map with keys from enum

Tags: java, dictionary, enums, java-8

I have following enum:

```
public enum ProductType {
    RED_MEAT, POULTRY, FISH, EGGS, NUTS, DAIRY, CERIALS_AND_GRAINS, FRUIT, VEGETABLES, OIL_AND_SUGARS
}
```

I would like to create map with keys from the `enum` and null values. I tried according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31113139/3014866) following code:

```
Map<ProductType, DietFrequency> diet = Arrays.stream(ProductType.values())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(productType -> productType, value -> null));
```

But I am getting `NullPointerException` here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure an [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) is more suited to your needs.

```
Map<ProductType, DietFrequency> diet = new EnumMap<>(ProductType.class);
```

An EnumMap is much more efficient than a HashMap, for enum values. By default, no mappings exist. Depending on your use case, that may be fine (`map.get(RED_MEAT)` returns null, which seems to be what you want), but if you want to do a containsKey() check or loop over entries, then you'll have to explicitly set the mappings to null:

```
Arrays.stream(ProductType.values()).forEach(v-> diet.put(v, null));
```