# How to convert enum with attribute to map using java8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream

- this answer doesn't math: [How to store enum to map using Java 8 stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112967/how-to-store-enum-to-map-using-java-8-stream-api)

I have an enum:

```
public enum SheetRows{
    totalActive("Total active");

    String value;

    SheetRows(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValueForTable() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

How to convert this enum to `HashMap<SheetRows, String>`?

I try to use:

```
HashMap<SheetRows, String> cellsMap = Arrays.asList(SheetRows.values()).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> v.getValueForTable()));
```

but this code isn't compile.

Comment: That's because `toMap` is written to return a `Map`, not a `HashMap`. Is that all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, the problem is that you're trying to assign a `Map` to `HashMap`

```java
Map<SheetRows, String> map = EnumSet.allOf(SheetRows.class)
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), SheetRows::getValueForTable));

System.out.println("map = " + map); // map = {totalActive=Total active}
```

---

If you really need to return a `HashMap`, you can also use the overload that takes a supplier and a mergeFunction like hereunder.

The mergeFunction will never be called since your enums are unique, so just choose a random one.

```java
HashMap<SheetRows, String> map = EnumSet.allOf(SheetRows.class)
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), SheetRows::getValueForTable, (o1, o2) -> o1, HashMap::new));

System.out.println("map = " + map); // map = {totalActive=Total active}
```

Comment: I thought @Yassin Hajaj that by default toMap method generates a HashMap, in my Java version 1.8 it calls toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, throwingMerger(), HashMap::new) in this case it could be casted using (HashMap) ?

Comment: Yes it could indeed @SergeyAfinogenov, but there is no guarantee that in the future, the JDK will keep sending a `HashMap`, this is an implementation detail, and the only thing that matters is the contract / spec

Comment: @SergeyAfinogenov See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055794/does-collectors-toset-always-return-a-hashset-what-is-the-contract)