# Return enum array for a list of given strings contained in the enum using streams

Tags: java, arraylist, enums, java-stream

I have an Enum of Strings like this:

```
public enum SomeEnum {

  STRING1("some value"),
  STRING2("some other value");
  STRING3("some third value");

  ...more strings...

  private String name;

  SomeEnum(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
```

And I have a List someStringList containing some Strings.

I want to iterate over someStringList and find the corresponding enums for it.

For example: The List contains the Strings "some value" and "some third value", then I would like to use the Java Stream-API to return me a List containing SomeEnum.STRING1 and SomeEnum.STRING3

Somehow I can't get this to work. I tried something like this:

```
    List<SomeEnum> enumList = Stream.of(someStringList).forEach( s -> Stream.of(SomeEnum.values()).filter(w -> w.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

but this doesn't compile because it doesn't return anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding enum value with Java 8 Stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807232/finding-enum-value-with-java-8-stream-api)

Comment: Unfortunately no, because in all similar questions I found it is a single String instead of a List of Strings

Comment: Simple to adapt once you have that `find` method in the accepted answer. Just stream over your list of strings and `map` with the result of `find`.

Comment: Have a stream of `SomeEnum` values, filter it by checking if the `someStringList` contains the `name` of the enum value being filtered and collect the filtered enum values into a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SomeEnum` you can build a `Map<String, SomeEnum>` from string name to enum and initialize it during class loading time. Then declare a public static method in your `SomeEnum` named `fromString` which returns an enum constant for a given string if one exists.

```
private static final Map<String, SomeEnum> stringToEnum = Arrays.stream(values())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(SomeEnum::toString, e -> e));

public static SomeEnum fromString(String name) {
    return stringToEnum.get(name);
}
```

Then use it in your client code. Here's how it looks.

```
List<SomeEnum> enumList = someStringList.stream()
    .map(SomeEnum::fromString)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Build a map from the string to the corresponding `SomeEnum` value:

```
Map<String, SomeEnum> map = 
    Arrays.stream(SomeEnum.values()).collect(toMap(SomeEnum::toString, s -> s));
```

(This can be done once and stored)

Then you can look up in this:

```
List<SomeEnum> enumList = someStringList.stream().map(map::get).collect(toList());
```

(You may or may not want to handle the case where a string isn't found in the map: for example, you could throw an exception, or drop such elements).