# Converting String to enum

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum Day {
  SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
  THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
 }
```

If my input is a "SUNDAY" as a `String`, how can I get the corresponding `Day.SUNDAY`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Day day = Day.valueOf("SUNDAY");
```