# Assign enum values based on value parameter in JAVA

Tags: java, enums

I have a card class:

```
public class Card{        
    private final Rank rank;
    public Rank rank() { return rank; }
    public Card(Rank rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }    
}
```

Where Rank is an enum defined as so:

```
enum Rank {
    TWO ("2"),
    THREE ("3"),
    FOUR ("4"),
    private final String rankNum;
    private Rank(String rankNum) { this.rankNum = rankNum; }
    public String rankNum(){ return rankNum; }
}
```

So my goal is to input a string "2" as a command line argument and then make a new card object with its rank value as TWO. If the input were "TWO" then it would be possible to do this but I do not know how to do it if the input is "2".

If the input were "TWO" I would do the following:

```
Card firstCard = new Card(Rank.args[0]);
```

I hope this question wasn't too badly phrased or obvious, as you can tell I'm still in my early stages, but I've searched this question for hours to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a String to an enum in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-java)

Comment: Use the `valueOf("YOUR_VALUE")`

Answer (score 0):

If your expected input is `"2"` (as opposed to `"TWO"`), you could add a utility static method in your enum.

Something in the lines of:

```
public static Rank forValue(String value) {
    // null/empty check
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    // iterates enum values
    for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
        // found a match
        if (r.rankNum().equals(value)) {
            return r;
        }
    }
    // iteration over, no match found
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

Comment: I can't even vote yet! This looks helpful I will try it out now. Thank you

Comment: Amazing thank you!! this worked perfectly. Except for one thing you wrote `values()` in line 7 but it needed to be `Rank.values()`

Comment: This would work but is inefficient to loop every time you lookup. Check my answer for a hashtable based solution that I believe is a very elegant and fast solution

Comment: OK point taken thank you... for the purpose of a class project it should suffice though :)

Comment: @triadiktyo Not discussing the logic of your solution, but you do know that `HashTable` is obsoleted in favor of `HashMap` for thread-unsafe, and `ConcurrentHashMap` for thread-safe mapping, right?

Comment: @AlexLama if you're looking to retrieve a `Rank` for both types of input, you can combine `Rank.valueOf(String s)` with my solution, and retrieve the first non-null result. **Edit** you might want to tweak the `NoSuchElementException` throwing in my solution and return `null` instead in that case.

Comment: Thanks Mena, in fact my program will only ever have `"2"` `"3"` etc. as inputs but I couldn't list these in an `enum` because they have to start with letters so your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You should check if your command line argument is equals to any Rank value, and then create your new Card

Answer (score 0):

Use Rank.lookupByNumber("2") to get Rank.TWO

```
import java.util.HashMap;

enum Rank {
    TWO("2"), THREE("3"), FOUR("4");

    private static final HashMap<String, Rank> lookupTable = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
            lookupTable.put(rank.rankNum, rank);
        }
    }

    private final String rankNum;

    private Rank(String rankNum) {
        this.rankNum = rankNum;
    }

    public String rankNum() {
        return rankNum;
    }

    public static Rank lookupByNumber(String number) {
        return lookupByNumber(number);
    }
}
```

In a static block you initialize a lookupTable with the strings you provide as keys. So you can very easily and very quickly grab the Rank enum by the String provided

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way then loop through the values of your `Enum`, and check if your given value matches with any value in the `Enum` constants.

```
String value = //given value Ex: "2"
for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
        if (rank.rankNum().equals(value)) {
            return rank;
        }
}
```

Comment: There is another way. Please have a look at my answer which I believe is a very elegant way to do it

Comment: @triadiktyo yes you can do this way also. I mean API doesn't proved a way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

What about this

```
public enum Rank {

    TWO ("2"),
    THREE ("3"),
    FOUR ("4");

    private String description;

    private Rank(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.description;
    }
```

Main:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

    if(args.length > 0) {
        String rank = args[0].trim();
        if (rank.equals(Rank.TWO.toString())) {
            System.out.println("entered rank is: " + Rank.TWO.getDescription());
        }
    }
}
```