# Java create enum from String

Tags: java, enums

I have enum class

```
public enum PaymentType {

    /**
     * This notify type we receive when user make first subscription payment.
     */
    SUBSCRIPTION_NEW("subscr_signup"),

    /**
     * This notify type we receive when user make subscription payment for next
     * month.
     */
    SUBSCRIPTION_PAYMENT("subscr_payment"),

    /**
     * This notify type we receive when user cancel subscription from his paypal
     * personal account.
     */
    SUBSCRIPTION_CANCEL("subscr_cancel"),

    /**
     * In this case the user cannot change the amount or length of the
     * subscription, they can however change the funding source or address
     * associated with their account. Those actions will generate the
     * subscr_modify IPN that we are receiving.
     */
    SUBSCRIPTION_MODIFY("subscr_modify"),

    /**
     * Means that the subscription has expired, either because the subscriber
     * cancelled it or it has a fixed term (implying a fixed number of payments)
     * and it has now expired with no further payments being due. It is sent at
     * the end of the term, instead of any payment that would otherwise have
     * been due on that date.
     */
    SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED("subscr_eot"),

    /** User have no money on card, CVV error, another negative errors. */
    SUBSCRIPTION_FAILED("subscr_failed");

    private String type;

    PaymentType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

When I try to create enum :

```
PaymentType type = PaymentType.valueOf("subscr_signup");
```

Java throws to me error :

```
IllegalArgumentException occured : No enum constant models.PaymentType.subscr_signup
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: I think you have to write a comparison method inside you enum

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2965252/5188230

Comment: create additional static method, which will search through values of enum

Comment: @wero it's not a duplicate. Your provided example is not a solution if String is not same enum value.

Comment: @GregKopff The correct answer is provided there.

Comment: @ssh Did you read the second answer of the provided question?

Comment: @ssh You might want to scroll a bit more than just for the accepted answer.

Comment: @chrylis thank you. That was I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add and use this method

```
public static PaymentType parse(String type) {
    for (PaymentType paymentType : PaymentType.values()) {
        if (paymentType.getType().equals(type)) {
            return paymentType;
        }
    }
    return null; //or you can throw exception
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Enum does not have ready to use method for this. You either need to use exact field names:

```
PaymentType.valueOf("SUBSCRIPTION_MODIFY");
```

Or write your own method, for example:

```
public static PaymentType fromString(String string) {
  for (PaymentType pt : values()) {
    if (pt.getType().equals(string)) {
      return pt;
    }
  }
  throw new NoSuchElementException("Element with string " + string + " has not been found");
}
```

So this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(PaymentType.fromString("subscr_modify"));
}
```

Prints:

```
SUBSCRIPTION_MODIFY
```

Answer (score 0):

`valueOf` returns the enum item whose identifier matches the string you passed in.
For instance:

```
PaymentType t = PaymentType.valueOf("SUBSCRIPTION_NEW");
```

If you want to get the enum item whose `type` field matches a given string, write a static method on `PaymentType` that loops through `PaymentType.values()` and returns the matching item.

Comment: I can't use it because I can't change constants.

Comment: Surely you can write a method.

Answer (score 0):

The `Enum` class `.valueOf()` method is comparing the String passed to it to the `name` property of the enum instance - the actual value of the instance name, so in your example, this would be `"SUBSCRIPTION_NEW"` rather than `"subscr_signup"`.

You will need to write a static method which returns the correct enum instance for the given value. For example:

```
public static PaymentType byTypeString(String type) {
    for (PaymentType instance : values()) {
        if (instance.type.equals(type)) {
            return instance;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No PaymentType enum instance for type: " + type);
}
```

Comment: Why not? If you can't modify the PaymentType enum, just add this as a static method somewhere else using the `getType()` accessor rather than `type` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
subscr_signup
```

is an enum variable value, not enum value.
So if you want to get enum based on its value name you have to do it that way:

```
PaymentType type = PaymentType.valueOf("SUBSCRIPTION_NEW");
```