# How to get enum constructor name from value in java?

Tags: java

I have enum like below

```
enum Car {
    lamborghini("900"),tata("2"),audi("50"),fiat("15"),honda("12");
    private String price;
    Car(String p) {
        price = p;
    }
    String getPrice() {
        return price;
    } 
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("All car prices:");
        System.out.println(Car.valueOf("lamborghini").getPrice());

        for (Car c : Car.values())
            System.out.println(c + " costs " 
                               + c.getPrice() + " thousand dollars.");
    }
}
```

This is working fine,But I have Input like **"900"** ,So I want to get that enumConstructorName like **lamborghini** ,How can I do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a String to an enum in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-java)

Comment: There's no direct way to do that. You'll have to iterate over each one, and compare your input with the price.

Comment: Iterate throuh all the cars, and find the one which has the price "900".

Comment: ok,Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @Soujanya look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2965252/3215527

Comment: btw, the terminology in this question is a bit confusing. `"900"` isn't the "name" of the constructor, it's the (first, and only) _argument_ to the constructor. Constructors don't really have names (unlike methods), unless you're in the nitty-gritty world of reflection, in which case a constructor's name is always `"<init>"`.

Answer (score 7):

```
Optional<Car> car = Arrays.stream(Car.values())
     .filter(c -> c.getPrice().equals(input))
     .findFirst();
```

Comment: Excellent use of Java 8 Streams and the filter function @andrucz! @resueman was correct in the Question's comments. You must iterate over all of the elements and make the comparison. Java 8 streams has made this much easier though.

Comment: I like that it uses Optional.  It handles the case that the user looks for a nonexistant price very well.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way is to have a Map you can lookup.

```
static final Map<String, Car> priceMap = values().stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.getPrice(), c -> c));

public static Car lookupPrice(String s) {
    return priceMap.get(s);
}
```

However, I would store a number in a field like int or double.

Answer (score 1):

This returns the name of the Enum:

`Car.lamborghini.name();`