# How to set Objects Enum type in constructor?

Tags: java, enums

I have following class:

```
public class Owner {

  private final Integer id;
  private final OwnerType type;

  public Owner(Integer iId, Enum eType) {
      this.id= iId;
      this.lastName = lName;
      this.type = eType // how should that work?
  } 

}
```

And

```
public enum OwnerType {
    HUMAN,INSTITUTION   
}
```

Which I am calling via:

```
try {
    File file = new File("resources/Owner.txt");
    Scanner fileContent = new Scanner(file);
    while (fileContent.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] person = fileContent.nextLine().split(" ");
            this.data.add(new Owner(owner[0],owner[1]));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException err){
        System.out.println(err);
    }
```

Where Owner.txt has a format of:

```
ID TYPE
```

Like that:

```
1 HUMAN
2 INSTITUTION
```

My question is:

How can I specify the `type` property of my Owner Object when I am calling the following?

```
new Owner(owner[0],owner[1])
```

Comment: what is 'owner' ? what type(s) does it hold?

Comment: Firstly, can you change the name of `Enum` so that it's *not* the name of a class in the `java.lang` package? It will make both your code and your question much simpler.

Comment: Your "constructor" name (`AccountOwner`) doesn't match the class name (`Owner`).

Comment: Past that, it sounds like you need `Enum.valueOf`

Comment: It looks like duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-java. By the way, you also need convert `String` to `Integer`.

Comment: Please post code that compiles, or at least, that has a compile error only in the problematic place. There is no variable named `owner`. And whatever array it is, it cannot match the parameters of the constructor. Why are you using `Enum` instead of `OwnerType` anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, the `Owner`'s constructor should receive an `OwnerType`, not just any `Enum`:

```
public Owner(Integer iId, OwnerType eType) {
    this.id= iId;
    this.type = eType;
}
```

When parsing the input file, you could use the [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) method to convert a string value to an `OwnerType`:

```
this.data.add
    (new Owner(Integer.parseInt(owner[0]), OwnerType.valueOf(owner[1])));
```

Answer (score 1):

Any Enumeration object have by default the method valueOf(String key), the what this method does is search into all defined values into your enum class and return the right one if find it.

For more info keep on eye on this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29)

In this particular case the enum;

```
public enum OwnerType {
    HUMAN,INSTITUTION   
}
```

if we use OwnerType.valueOf("HUMAN"), will return the enum type HUMAN

Here use this:

```
try {
    File file = new File("resources/Owner.txt");
    Scanner fileContent = new Scanner(file);
    while (fileContent.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] person = fileContent.nextLine().split(" ");
        this.data.add(new Owner(person[0],OwnerType.valueOf(person[1])));
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException err){
    System.out.println(err);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Code dumps without explanation are not useful.