# Get Enum instance

Tags: java, enums

I have an `Enum`:

```
public enum Type {

    ADMIN(1), 
    HIRER(2), 
    EMPLOYEE(3);

    private final int id;

    Type(int id){
        this.id = id;       
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

How can I get a **`Type`** enum passing an **`id`** property?

Comment: You could iterate the `Type` values and look for your `id`; or populate a `Map<Integer, Type>`.

Comment: [This might be exactly what you need.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2965252/1682559) (except that you have an `int id` instead of a `String text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. I have created a method which searches type using id:

```
public static Type getType(int id) {

    for (Type type : Type.values()) {
        if (id == type.getId()) {
            return type;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can build a map to do this lookup.

```
static final Map<Integer, Type> id2type = new HashMap<>();
static {
    for (Type t : values())
        id2type.put(t.id, t);
}
public static Type forId(int id) {
    return id2type.get(id);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution the most. It is clean and has the best performance for arbitrarily big enums.

Answer (score 2):

Create a method inside the `Type` class returning the `Enum` instances:

```
Type get(int n) {
    switch (n) {
    case 1:
        return Type.ADMIN;
    case 2:
        return Type.EMPLOYEE;
    case 3:
        return Type.HIRER;
    default:
        return null;
    }

}
```

**TIP:** you need to add `default` in `switch-case` or add a `return null` at the end of the method to avoid compiler errors.

---

**UPDATE** (thanks to [@AndyTurner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner)):

> It would be better to loop and refer to the id field, so you're not duplicating the IDs.

```
Type fromId(int id) {
    for (Type t : values()) {
        if (id == t.id) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to loop and refer to the `id` field, so you're not duplicating the IDs.

Comment: @AndyTurner updated answer... but... why you say I'm duplicating the id's? I'm missing something? or you mean write a line by each id??

Comment: I mean that if you want to change the id for `ADMIN`, you'd have to change it in two places (the instance declaration and the switch).

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhh.... touché! ^_^

Comment: It would be even better to populate a `Map<Integer,Type>` that is filled in the constructor and then just look up the id...

Comment: @brimborium yes, but that is Peter answer....

Comment: @JordiCastilla I just saw. ;)

Comment: Note: every time you call `values()` it creates a new array of the enum values.  It has to do this because it doesn't know if you are going to mutate it or not.