# Can I convert a string to enum without macros in Rust?

Tags: string, parsing, enums, macros, rust

For example, if I have code like:

```
enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Baz,
    Bat,
    Quux
}

impl Foo {
    from(input: &str) -> Foo {
        Foo::input
    }
}
```

This will obviously fail because `input` is not a method of Foo. I can manually type:

```
from(input: &str) -> Foo {
    match(input) {
        "Bar" => Foo::Bar,
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

but I'm not getting the automatic convenience.

It looks like Java has a [string lookup function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/lookup-enum-by-string-value) on enums for this specific purpose.

Is it possible to get this without writing my own macro or importing one from a crate?

Comment: What if instead of `"Bar"` you need `"Foo::Bar"` or `"my_module::Foo::Bar"` or `"bar"`? That helps explain why there's no pre-made way to do this. There's nothing in the standard library, beyond that you would just be asking for a library / tool recommendation.

Comment: I don't think your edit on my answer is necessary: you asked for automatic convenience, which you get with the crates I mentioned and you don't have to write you own macro, because the crates already provide the macro.

Answer (score 93):

You should implement [std::str::FromStr](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) trait.

```
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Baz,
    Bat,
    Quux,
}

impl FromStr for Foo {

    type Err = ();

    fn from_str(input: &str) -> Result<Foo, Self::Err> {
        match input {
            "Bar"  => Ok(Foo::Bar),
            "Baz"  => Ok(Foo::Baz),
            "Bat"  => Ok(Foo::Bat),
            "Quux" => Ok(Foo::Quux),
            _      => Err(()),
        }
    }
}



fn main() {
    // Use it like this
    let f = Foo::from_str("Baz").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(f, Foo::Baz);
}
```

Code-generation (aka automatic convenience) and reflections usually bear a cost. In practice, it is unlikely that you will end up with more than a few enum variants.

Run in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c78f940ff91314f95c147d1e55f4a4b7)

Comment: Is there any fancy way to get the compiler to check that the output list is exhaustive without any runtime cost?

Answer (score 45):

Same disclaimer as in other answers: "without macros" isn't possible.

Extending on the highest voted answer. As noted in [this thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/convert-a-string-to-enum/38845) the combination of `custom_derive` + `enum_derive` is somewhat outdated. Modern Rust doesn't need a solution based on `custom_derive` anymore.

A modern alternative is [`strum`](https://github.com/Peternator7/strum). Usage could look like this:

```rust
use strum_macros::EnumString;
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(EnumString)]
enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Baz,
    Bat,
    Quux
}

fn example_usage(input: &str) -> Foo {
    Foo::from_str(input).unwrap()
}
```

Note: You need both `strum` and `strum_macros` in your `Cargo.toml`.

`strum` also gives some nice flexibility regarding the string representation. From the [docs](https://github.com/Peternator7/strum/wiki/Derive-EnumString):

> Note that the implementation of `FromStr` by default only matches on the name of the variant. There is an option to match on different case conversions through the `#[strum(serialize_all = "snake_case")]` type attribute.

Answer (score 28):

**Edit:** The answer is no. Rust does not provide reflection and usually use `#[derive]` for that kind of tasks.

You can use the crates [`enum_derive`](https://crates.io/crates/enum_derive) and [`custom_derive`](https://crates.io/crates/custom_derive) to do what you want.

Here is an exemple:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate custom_derive;
#[macro_use]
extern crate enum_derive;

custom_derive! {
    #[derive(Debug, EnumFromStr)]
    enum Foo {
        Bar,
        Baz,
        Bat,
        Quux
    }
}

fn main() {
    let variable: Foo = "Bar".parse().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", variable);
}
```

the `derive` of the custom `EnumFromStr` allows you to use the `parse` method to get a `Foo`.

Comment: If it is not what you want, please edit your question, because, as I said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070244/can-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-without-macros-in-rust/39070533#comment-65517006), I don't see why it does not answer your question.

Comment: Great answer, but not to this question. I was also looking for an answer.

Comment: I thought the OP explicitly asked "without macros".

Comment: I think the answer is that it is not possible without a macro, although I would have this double-checked by a more experienced Rustacean before I try editing the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Make sure to check out the other answer about macros: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62711168/2650622
The crates linked here seem unmaintained