# Is it possible to convert from type A to B and from B to A using a single std::convert::From implementation?

Tags: rust, type-conversion, traits

## Problem

I want to write a single function that allows me to convert from type A (in this case, `u8`) to type B (a custom type), and then back from type B to type  A. According to the first paragraph of the [entry about the traits `From` and `Into` of Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/from_into.html):

> The `From` and `Into` traits are inherently linked, and this is actually part of its implementation. If you are able to convert type A from type B, then it should be easy to believe that we should be able to convert type B to type A.

However, implementing `From` (i.e.`impl From<A> for B`) allowed me to convert from A to B and *only* A to B, except in two different ways (still not sure why two ways are necessary but anyway). Can I convert from B to A using the same implementation? Or is there no way to use the information already there?

### What I have tried

I tried implementing `From` (or `TryFrom` in this case) on my type `NormalMneumonic` like so

```rust
impl TryFrom<&str> for NormalMneumonic {
    type Error = Error;
    fn try_from(value: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match value {
            "JP" => Ok(Self::Jump),
            // --snip--
            _ => Err("Input is not a normal menumonic."),
        }
    }
}
```

With that I'm able to do

```rust
let mneumonic_1 /*: Result<NormalMneumonic, _>*/ = NormalMneumonic::try_from("JP");
let mneumonic_2: Result<NormalMneumonic, _> = "JP".try_into();
assert_eq!(mneumonic_1, mneumonic_2);
```

but I haven't found a way to convert, in this case, from `NormalMneumonic` back into `&str`.
I'm looking for something like

```rust
let mneumonic_string = NormalMneumonic::Jump.try_into(); // or perhaps &str::try_from(NormalMneumonic::Jump)
```

## Some context

I'm trying to write an assembler and a linker for a simplified assembly language using Rust. One of the data types I have defined to help with that is `NormalMneumonic`, which is just an enum with a variant for each valid mneumonic.

On writing the assembler, I'll need to read some text file and write some binary, and on linking I'll need to read back some binary files and write a different binary file. With that in mind, I was looking for a way to convert back and forth between a string slice (`&str`) or a byte (`u8`) and a `NormalMneumonic` variant.

From the quote I mentioned, I thought converting back and forth between types was the use case for the `From` trait, but it seems the book in this case just uses misleading language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a `From<A> for B` implementation will not create a `From<B> for A` implementation.

The `From` trait is composed of only a single method `fn from(a: A) -> B`. With just this signature, would you be able to create the reverse implementation for all `A` and `B`? Of course not! And the compiler will not look at the existing implementation's body to try to deduce the other. For one thing, many conversions are lossy, many conversions are fallible, and may have hurdles converting one way that don't exist when converting the opposite direction. So even if the compiler did look at the existing implementation, its not practical or even possible in general.

> From the quote I mentioned, I thought converting back and forth between types was the use case for the `From` trait, but it seems the book in this case just uses misleading language.

Indeed, you've misinterpreted the quote. It is essentially saying the same thing twice, but in a different context: *"convert type A from type B"* is the same operation as *"convert type B to type A"*, both are `B -> A`, just the subject of the phrasing has changed. And this reflects the only difference between `From` and `Into`. The syntaxes `A::from(b)` and `b.into()` (with inferred `A`) cannot be done with a single trait.

---

If you're looking to make your life easier when dealing with enums, as already mentioned, the [strum](https://crates.io/crates/strum) crate has many derive macros designed to:

- convert to string: [`IntoStaticStr`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/derive.IntoStaticStr.html) and/or [`ToString`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/derive.ToString.html)
- convert from a string: [`EnumString`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/derive.EnumString.html)
- convert from `u8`: [`FromRepr`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/derive.FromRepr.html)
- (converting to `u8` can be done with just `as u8` if `#[repr(u8)]` is added)

See these existing answers for other options:

- [How do I get an enum as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710187/how-do-i-get-an-enum-as-a-string)
- [Can I convert a string to enum without macros in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070244/can-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-without-macros-in-rust)
- [How do I match enum values with an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028854/how-do-i-match-enum-values-with-an-integer)

Comment: I indeed was a bit too naive to consider `From` would allow lossy conversion but also infer `B -> A` from `A -> B`. It would be interesting to have something like that though, and theoretically possible. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: For the record, converting to and from `u8` or other numerical type can be done using [`num_enum`](https://crates.io/crates/num_enum) and deriving from `TryFromPrimitive` and `IntoPrimitive`. There's a comment on a Rust RFC mentioning crates as the way to go for this use case.

Comment: @tomaz-suller Got a link to the RFC? There are many crates for using enums like this, so I'm curious if the Rust team is considering one of them better than the others.

Comment: I was looking for an answer on the GitHub app on my phone, and I couldn't find it on my history. Sorry :-/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [strum_macros](https://crates.io/crates/strum_macros) can help.

It can generate code to convert enum value to &str

```rust
use strum_macros::IntoStaticStr;

#[derive(IntoStaticStr)]
enum NormalMneumonic {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That would indeed let me associate each variant with a `&str`, but it seems not with a `u8` at the same time (as I was hoping to do), from the context I gave on the question

Comment: I would also have to write code to convert from `&str` into my enum type, which would mean two places in my code saying the same thing, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid