# Interpreting user input as an enum instance

Tags: java, enums, java.util.scanner

I have the following Enum:

```
public enum Food {
APPLE,
BREAD,
PIE,
STEAK;
}
```

I want to store the user's chosen food like so `Food food = scanner.next()` (obviously this is incorrect). What would be a good way to do it?

Comment: Possible option would be to create a map of String : Food and use that based on String input from user.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/lookup-enum-by-string-value

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Remember to invoke `toUpperCase` on `scanner.next()`

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

Food food;
String input = scanner.next();
for (Food item : Food.values()) {
    if(input.equals(item.name())) food = item;

}
```