# What is benefit from using fromValue function instead of valueOf, java enums?

Tags: java, enums, value-of

I see some programmers use in enums structure function called fromValue. What is it purpose, if we can use valueOf? For example, I found something like this:

```
public static FooEnum fromValue(String v) {  
    return valueOf(v);  
}
```

Comment: If the implementation is like this then we can only guess - and my guess would be it's meant to be more readable (I'm not saying it is though).

Comment: Yeah I've never seen this and I don't understand it.

Comment: Readability can also be improved by standardization. Maybe this team agreed to always use the above signature for getting an enum from a String, to make it uniform for both complex cases where there is error handling or value mapping, and simple cases (like above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have an invalid String value:

```
public static FooEnum fromValue(String v) {
    try {
        return valueOf(v);
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
        return FooEnum.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it is clear. It means that method 'fromValue' as presented in question is pointless or added for readability purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Think about an enum that has a string property with a different value then the name of the enum.

```
public enum FooEnum {
   A("foo"),
   B("bar"),
   ;
  ...
 }
```

Then you need such an method for a lookup of the property values.
See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2965252/3828323)

Comment: I got it, but I was interested whether it has deeper meaning. I mean coding conventions, readability ect.

Comment: Ah okay. We use it like @daniu mentioned, to handle invalid values and throwing an exception that indicates a developer failure. So it is more an internal conding convention.