# how to get enum id using its enum name

Tags: java, enums, cuba-platform, cuba

```
public enum EnumCountry implements EnumClass<Integer> {

  Ethiopia(1),
  Tanzania(2),
  private Integer id;

  EnumCountry(Integer value) {
    this.id = value;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @Nullable
  public static EnumCountry fromId(Integer id) {
    for (EnumCountry at : EnumCountry.values()) {
      if (at.getId().equals(id)) {
        return at;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I have the code like above.
How can I get Enum Id using its Enum Name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/lookup-enum-by-string-value

Answer (score 9):

You can simply add a method like below -

```
  public static int getId(String enumCountryName) {
     return EnumCountry.valueOf(enumCountryName).getId();
  }
```

So the complete class will be like this -

```
public enum EnumCountry implements EnumClass<Integer> {

  Ethiopia(1),
  Tanzania(2);
  private Integer id;

  EnumCountry(Integer value) {
    this.id = value;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @Nullable
  public static EnumCountry fromId(Integer id) {
    for (EnumCountry at : EnumCountry.values()) {
      if (at.getId().equals(id)) {
        return at;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

 public static int getId(String enumCountryName) {
     return EnumCountry.valueOf(enumCountryName).getId();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as calling its getId() method:

```
Ethiopia.getId()
```

Or:

```
Tanzania.getId()
```

Or, assuming you meant you have the string `"Ethiopia"`, then you can also do `EnumCountry.valueOf("Ethiopia").getId()`.  Hope that answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

You can't because their types are incompatible - i.e. `String` vs `Integer`. On the other hand, you can add a method that returns a `String` that combines `name` and `id`:

```
public enum EnumCountry implements EnumClass<Integer> {

  Ethiopia(1),
  Tanzania(2); // replaced comma with semicolon

  private Integer id;

  // ...

  public String getNameId() {
      // returns "Ethiopa 1"
      return name() + " " + id;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If name is present as `String`, simply do this,

```
int getId(String name){
  EnumCountry country = EnumCountry.valueOf(name);
  return country.getId();
}
```