# map json string to enum

Tags: java, json, spring, enums, lombok

I have the following `class` and `enum`s:

```
import lombok.Data;
// other imports...

@Data
public class MapTest{
    private MyFirstEnum myFirstEnum;
    private MySecondEnum mySecondEnum;
}

public enum MyFirstEnum{
    MY_FIRST_ENUM1,
    MY_FIRST_ENUM2
}

public enum MySecondEnum {
    MY_SECOND_ENUM1,
    MY_SECOND_ENUM2
}
```

and this spring controller:

```
@PostMapping("/testMap")
@ResponseBody
public void TestMap(@RequestBody MapTest mapTest){

}
```

Since [an enum can be looked up by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/604426/1092181) what I would like to do is to post a `json` to the controller and that the appropriate props will be serialized by their name:

```
{
    "myFirstEnum": "MY_FIRST_ENUM1",
    "mySecondEnum": "MY_SECOND_ENUM2"
}
```

I've tried to set up a `@JsonDeserialize` but i couldn't get the type of the enum inside the overridden function:

```
// what type should i use here?
public static class StringToEnum extends JsonDeserializer<???> {
    // how do i get the type of the current enum?
    @Override
    public ??? deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ??? res = Enum.valueOf(p.getText());
        return res;
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I've failed to mention that i'm using [lombok's @data attribute](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) for automatically generating getters and setters, which doesn't work well with enum bindings (not sure why).
I guess that laziness comes with a price.

Comment: Write two JsonDeserializers, once by replacing your ??? with `MyFirstEnum` and next by `MySecondEnum`, in case you still want to write custom deserializers.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that the way Jackson handles enums *by default*?

Comment: Jackson handles it by default, it seems `MapTest` has setter / getter missing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be serialized automatically via jackson but you can force it via **@JsonCreator**
Redefine your enums as

```
public enum MyFirstEnum{
    MY_FIRST_ENUM1,
    MY_FIRST_ENUM2;

    @JsonCreator
    public static MyFirstEnum fromString(String raw) {
        return MyFirstEnum.valueOf(raw.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Similarly define your second enum as well in the similar manner.

**Imp Note (Mandatory)**

**MapTest** should have public setter / getter for both enums (if declared private, preferred), or declare them public (should be avoided, not preferred)

Comment: how can will i use the `fromString` function once it's declared?

Comment: You don't need to use it, jackson library will use it. BTW you can still call MyFirstEnum.fromValue("MY_FIRST_ENUM1").