# Create List of enum from comma separated String in Java

Tags: java, java-8, spring-el, spring-config

I need to create a List of enum from a comma separated String. I have some configurations in properties file which are mainly a list of `HttpStatus`

like:

```
some.config=TOO_MANY_REQUESTS,GATEWAY_TIMEOUT,BAD_GATEWAY
```

This configurations can be bind to a LIST as:

```
@Value("#{'${some.config}'.split(',')}")
private List<HttpStatus> statuses;
```

Now can this be done with a single line of my code. I am receiving the String as following:

```
 @Bean(name = "somebean")
 public void do(@Value("${some.config:}") String statuses) throws IOException {

        private List<HttpStatus>  sList = StringUtils.isEmpty(statuses) ? 
        globalSeries : **Arrays.asList(statuses.split("\\s*,\\s*"));**

 }
```

**Arrays.asList(series.split("\s*,\s*"));** will create a List of string, now can I create a List of enum instead, otherwise I need to iterate the temp List then create a List of enum.

Comment: How about something like `List<YourEnum> list = Stream.of(yourData.split(delimiter).map(YourEnum::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList())`? Anyway possibly related: [Lookup Java enum by string value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/604424)

Comment: @Pshemo I though the same, just somehow handle invalid input by catching `IllegalArgumentException` somewhere

Comment: Are you sure you want a `List` (allow duplicates, maintain an order)? For most practical use cases, you want a `Set`, likely an `EnumSet`. `Arrays.stream(statuses.split(",")) .map(s -> HttpStatus.valueOf(s.trim())) .collect(Collectors.toCollection( () -> EnumSet.noneOf(HttpStatus.class) ))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just use a stream and map all the `String` values into the `Enum` values using `Enum#valueOf`

```
Arrays.stream(statuses.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
      .map(HttpStatus::valueOf)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a Pattern to accomplish the task at hand:

```
Pattern.compile(regex)
       .splitAsStream(myString)
       .map(HttpStatus::valueOf)
       .collect(toList());
```