# How do I return an enum as a string for my WebDriverManager in Java?

Tags: java

How do I create an enum as a String and call it for my WebDriverManager?

**Resource I'm following**: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/enums.html#enum-example

I want to clean up my webdrivermanager and make it cleaner and flexible by providing enums. Here is my attempt as I'd like every browser type to be returned as a String.

**Enums**:

```
public enum BrowserEnv {

    CHROME("chrome"),
    FIREFOX("firefox"),
    IE("internet explorer"),
    SAFARI("safari");

    private String browser;

    BrowserEnv(String browserName){
        browserName = browserName.CHROME;
        
    }
```

**My webdrivermanager code:**

I want to call on `BrowserEnv` but not sure how to get it to work.

```
public WebDriver initializeDriver() {

    if (BrowserEnv.CHROME)) { // I want to be able to change these on the fly
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (BrowserEnv.CHROME)) { // Want to be able to change this anytime
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
}
```

[UPDATE] - Code below is what I'm trying to work out based on comments and continuous solutions until I get it to work.

Moved `driver` decisions to enums.
used `if` statements to launch another browser in case chrome in this example should fail. Currently, `getDriver` is asking for `WebDriverManager` to return as an object.

```
public enum BrowserEnv {

    CHROME("chrome"),
    FIREFOX("firefox");

    private String browser;

    BrowserEnv(String browserName) {
        this.browser = browserName;
    }

    public WebDriverManager getWebDriverManager() {
        if (this == BrowserEnv.CHROME) {
            return WebDriverManager.chromedriver();
        } else if (this == BrowserEnv.FIREFOX) {
            return WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver();
        }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
            if (this == BrowserEnv.CHROME) {
                return new ChromeDriver();
            } else if (this == BrowserEnv.FIREFOX) {
                return new FirefoxDriver();
            }
        }
    }
```

Initializing browser a `Base` class

```
public WebDriver initializeDriver(BrowserEnv browser) {
    setUrl();

    browser.getWebDriverManager().setup();
    driver = browser.getDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: @hev1 Thank you for the reply, it seems that is not working for me. It I get the following message: `It is illegal to access static member 'CHROME' from enum constructor or instance initializer`.

Comment: may be it should be `browser = browserName`

Comment: @deadshot That didn't seem to work either. I have updated my questions and examples above as there was unecessary info and I just wanted to cut straight to the chase.

Comment: I will leave examples updated example of how I'm working through this based on comments so its easier for everyone to follow what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Beginner_SQA this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/2965252/9050514

Comment: I'm calling this answered as this was about the enums. I'll make a post about the new issue I'm having based on my [UPDATE] section. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all `driver` related decision making to your enum.

```
public enum BrowserEnv {

    CHROME("chrome"), FIREFOX("firefox"), IE("internet explorer"), SAFARI("safari");

    private String browser;

    BrowserEnv(String browserName){
        this.browser = browserName;        
    }
    
    public WebdriverManager getWebDriverManager() {
        switch(this) {
            case CHROME:
                return WebdriverManager.chromedriver();
                break;
            case FIREFOX:
                return WebdriverManager.firefoxdriver();
                break;
            case IE:
                return WebdriverManager.iedriver();
                break;
            case SAFARI:
                return WebdriverManager.safaridriver();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            
        }
    }
    
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        switch(this) {
            case CHROME:
                return new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case FIREFOX:
                return new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            case IE:
                return new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
            case SAFARI:
                return new SafariDriver();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize and drive the browser type externally.

```
public WebDriver initializeDriver(BrowserEnv browser) {
    browser.getWebDriverManager().setup();
    driver = browser.getDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: Wow. That's alot more elaborate than I thought. Can you modify `initializeDriver` to include the `If` statement in case chrome can't be invoked?

Comment: I would really like to have a back up browser launch in case one fails.

Comment: Then you can specify in the default switch-cases used internally the fallback browser.

Comment: I'll give it a try and update my post to your solution. Thank you.

Comment: Before I post my fix based on your answer, will I need to add the IF statements in both `getWebDriverManager` and `getDriver` ?

Comment: Depends which one is more likely to fail. Use only in the function that is more likely to fail. Another way to avoid IF-ELSE is to perform a `null` check in `getWebDriverManager`. If it throws a NullPointerException, you initialize with the fallback. You can do this in both and avoid IF-ELSE by using TRY-CATCH-FINALLY instead.

Comment: I'll most likely do chrome and firefox for now to show in my update and get your blessing on it lol

Comment: Haha! Sure thing.

Comment: Ok I updated my code, and so far I've been able to work out the `getWebdriverManager`. IntelliJ sees `getDriver` as an error and is asking to return it as an object. Does that seem right to you? Please see update.

Comment: Correction: `getDriver` is asking for `getWebDriverManager` to be returned as an object.

Comment: I don't see any reference in the update where `getDriver` would have anything to do with `getWebDriverManager`.

Comment: yea, it's odd. Shall we take this conversation to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217463/discussion-between-beginner-sqa-and-zeeshan-siddiqui).