# Creating a method that can only input a certain types of strings that are predetermined

Tags: java, string, types

I have the following type of Strings

```
"Move 1 place forwards"; 
"Move 1 place backwards;
```

Can I create a type called 2dMotion, where a method can only take in these two strings as arguments in Java.

```
public 2dMotion message(){ return "Move 1 place forwards"; }
```

For example if a method was classed that had 2dMotion as an input then it wouldn't be able to input anything but those 2 sentences

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an enum value from a string value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/how-to-get-an-enum-value-from-a-string-value-in-java)

Comment: @HanchenJiang enum is the best solution, but not the only solution.

Comment: In Java, a class or enum name (type) cannot start with a number.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Samer, I know English is not your primary language, but I am sorry to say that your post doesn't make any sense. Because of that, your question is being voted for closing due to lack of clarity. Write your problem in your language and run it thru Google translate or similar service. Then come here and post the English translation. We won't be able to help you unless we understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare them as constants in a class, and provide direct access to them by making them public:

```
public MyClass {
    public static final MOTION_FORWARD = "Move 1 place forward";
    public static final MOTION_BACKWARDS = "Move 1 place backwards";
    // Rest of the class omitted

}
```

Or, a better solution is to use an Enum.

```
public enum MOTION {
    FORWARD("Move 1 place forward"),BACKWARDS("Move 1 place backwards");
    
    private final String val;
    private MOTION(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    
    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

To use the constant, simply use `MyClass.MOTION_FORWARD`. To use the enum, you could  do `MOTION.FORWARD.getVal();`

Lastly, as good practice, you should override `toString()` method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return val;
}
```

Even though this method does the same as `getVal()`, it is consider good practice to do so. If you would like to remove one of those methods, it should be the `getVal()` method. Also, even though the enum solution involves more code, it is also considered to be a better solution. Also, when you override `toString()`, it allows to return the value of the enum without invoking `toString()` or `getVal()` directly. For example, `System.out.println(MOTION.BACKWARDS);` prints out "Move 1 place backwards".

Comment: But this doesn't solve my problem because I'm looking also to have these ENUMS as inputs, I've updated my question to explain what I mean

Comment: @SamerAk I don't see any updates to your question.